# Why can't I pickle this object?

Tags: python

I have  a class (below):

```
class InstrumentChange(object):
    '''This class acts as the DTO object to send instrument change information from the
       client to the server. See InstrumentChangeTransport below
    '''
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self._changed = None

    def _method_name(self, text):
        return text.replace(' ','_').lower()

    def _what_changed(self):
        ''' Denotes the column that changed on the instrument returning the column_name of what changed.'''
        if not self._changed:
            self._changed = self._method_name(self.kwargs.pop('What Changed'))

        return self._changed

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        for key in self.kwargs.iterkeys():
            if self._method_name(key) == attr:
                return self.kwargs[key]

    def __str__(self):
        return "Instrument:%s" % self.kwargs

    __repr__ = __str__

    what_changed = property(_what_changed)
```

When I run the following test:

```
def test_that_instrumentchangetransport_is_picklable(self):
        test_dict = {'Updated': 'PAllum', 'Description': 'BR/EUR/BRAZIL/11%/26/06/2017/BD',
        'Ask Q': 500, 'Bbg': 'On', 'C Bid': 72.0, 'Benchmark': 'NL/USD/KKB/7.000%/03/11/2009/BD',
        'ISIN': 'XS0077157575', 'Bid YTM': 0.0, 'Bid Q': 100, 'C Ask': 72.25, 'Ask YTM': 0.0, 'Bid ASW': 0.0,
        'Position': 1280000, 'What Changed': 'C Bid', 'Ask ASW': 0.0}
        ins_change = InstrumentChangeTransport(**test_dict)
        assert isinstance(ins_change, InstrumentChangeTransport)

        # Create a mock filesystem object
        file = open('testpickle.dat', 'w')
        file = Mock()
        pickle.dump(ins_change, file)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python23\lib\site-packages\nose-0.11.0-py2.3.egg\nose\case.py", line 183, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "C:\Code\branches\demo\tests\test_framework.py", line 142, in test_that_instrumentchangetransport_is_picklable
    pickle.dump(ins_change, file)
  File "C:\Python23\Lib\copy_reg.py", line 83, in _reduce_ex
    dict = getstate()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I've looked at the pickle docs, but I don't quite get it.

Any ideas?

Ben

Comment: As a side note: 'key in self.kwargs.iterkeys()' generates a list of keys and searches through them. Better use 'key in self.kwargs', which tries to do a hashtable lookup (faster).

Comment: When asking for help debugging something, it helps to provide enough code to reproduce the problem. It helps even more to delete everything irrelevant from the code you post.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your code has several minor "side" issues: the sudden appearance of a 'Transport' in the class name used in the test (it's not the class name that you're defining), the dubious trampling over built-in identifier `file` as a local variable (don't do that -- it doesn't hurt here, but the habit of trampling over built-in identifiers will cause mysterious bugs one day), the misuses of `Mock` that has already been noted, the default use of the slowest, grungiest pickling protocol and text rather than binary for the pickle file.

However, at the heart, as @coonj says, is the lack of state control. A "normal" class doesn't need it (because `self.__dict__` gets pickled and unpickled by default in classes missing state control and without other peculiarities) -- but since you're overriding `__getattr__` that doesn't apply to your class.  You just need two more very simple methods:

```
def __getstate__(self): return self.__dict__
def __setstate__(self, d): self.__dict__.update(d)
```

which basically tell `pickle` to treat your class just like a normal one, taking `self.__dict__` as representing the whole of the instance state, despite the existence of the `__getattr__`.

Comment: @coonj, I guess people have a hard time seeing why one should need to define the state-handling methods since normally they're not needed (and nowhere is it clearly documented that `__getattr__` makes them necessary).

Answer (score 8):

It is failing because it can't find `__getstate__()` for your object.  Pickle needs these to determine how to pickle/unpickle the object.  You just need the `__getstate__()` and `__setstate__()` methods.

See the TextReader example in the docs: http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

**Update**: I just looked at the [sourceforge page for the Mock module,](http://python-mock.sourceforge.net/) and I think you are also using it incorrectly.
You are mocking a file-object, but when pickle tries to read from it, it won't get anything back which is why `getattr()` returns none.

Answer (score 2):

```
    file = open('testpickle.dat', 'w')
    file = Mock()
```

You are losing here reference to the opened file. Might that be a problem?

Comment: This seems to be the likely cause of the problem.