# Custom instance unpickling in Python: should the object dictionary be updated, or is replacing it OK?

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

When defining how objects of a certain class should be unpickled, via [__setstate__](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-normal-class-instances), I gather that it is safe to do

```
def __setstate__(self, dict_returned_by_pickle):
    self.__dict__.update(dict_returned_by_pickle)
```

when the pickled state is a dictionary.  This is what I have seen in an [answer here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049849/why-cant-i-pickle-this-object).

However, is this a safety measure, taken just in case `self.__dict__` contains some data when `__setstate__` is called?  or is it simply faster and cleaner than doing

```
self.__dict__ = dict_returned_by_pickle
```

which forces the old `self.__dict__` to be garbage collected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing it is fine. That is what the [borg pattern](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531/) does.

The original dict will be garbage collected if there are no other references to it.