# How to use ordered dicts in mako templates?

Tags: python, templates, mako

I am using the `Bunch` code from here:

- [How to use dicts in Mako templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352252/how-to-use-dicts-in-mako-templates)

And it works great. Except now I need to use Python 2.7's `collections.OrderedDict` and the `Bunch` code unorders the results.

I've taken a few swipes, but I'm not sure how to rewrite `Bunch` to support ordered dicts. Can anyone help? My code is here:

- https://github.com/ACLARKNET/vanity_aclark_net/blob/master/src/vanity_app/vanity_app/views.py

Comment: As it turns out, I think I can pass dicts in to mako templates as expected. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ditching the Bunch code in favor of the following syntax:

```
<span class="badge mini-classifier-pop-up" data-original-title="${classifier}"
    style="background: ${colors[stub][1]}"><i class="${icon}"></i></span>
```