# How can you pass a user configurable dict into a class instance

Tags: python, class, dictionary, oop, text-files

I have a class that makes objects allowing me to access properties of an experimental camera system. I have some configuration properties saved in a dict for where certain cameras should be initially located. As these initial settings may vary I cannot hard code them into the class but need them separate in a text file that I access using the json library.

Is there a way to pass the dict into a class so its key value pairs can be used?

**Simplified code**

```
import any_dict_01
import json

data = any_dict_01


class dummy(data):

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = data


    def getDict(self):
        print(self.data)


a = dummy()
a.getDict()
```

**Working Code**

based on hints and advice from karl in the comments under the question I figured out how to do it (I hope karl puts his comments as an answer so I can accept it).

```
import json


data = 'my_rig.txt'


class dummy:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data


    def getDict(self):
        with open(data) as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        print(data)


a =dummy()
theDict = a.getDict(data)
```

Comment: You're nearly there. A typical constructor looks like `def __init__(self, data): self.data = data`

Comment: `class dummy(data):` -> `class Dummy:`

Comment: `data = any_dict_01` does **not** make `data` be any particular `dict` defined by the `any_dict_01` module. It makes `data` be *another name* for that same *module*.

Comment: Anyway, this question isn't really about classes. The way you get information into the __init__ method is the same way that you get information into *any ordinary function*: by giving it a *parameter*, and passing the information in as an *argument*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel if you put that as an answer, the 2 comments merged I will accept it as based on that I wrote some code that does work, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By request:

`data = any_dict_01` does **not** make `data` be any particular dict defined by the `any_dict_01` module. It makes `data` be *another name* for *that same module*.

Anyway, this question isn't really about classes. The way you get information into the `__init__` method is the same way that you get information into *any ordinary function*: by giving it a *parameter*, and passing the information in as an *argument*.

Answer (score 1):

Your code would work by fixing the last part like this:

```
   def __init__(self, data):
      self.data = data

   def getDict(self):
      return self.data

a = dummy(data)
theDict=a.getDict()
```

You can make the dict accessible with dot notation, as if it were a class instance, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352252/how-to-use-dicts-in-mako-templates).

Comment: (OP actually needs to change their constructor as well)

Answer (score 1):

```
class dummy:
    def __init__(self, my_dict):
        self.my_dict = my_dict
```