# Storing dictionary path in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Brand new to python, Let's say I have a dict:

```
kidshair = {'allkids':{'child1':{'hair':'blonde'},
                      'child2':{'hair':'black'},
                      'child3':{'hair':'red'},
                      'child4':{'hair':'brown'}}}
```

If child3 changes their hair colour regularly, I might want to write an application to speed up the data maintenance. In this example i'd use:

```
kidshair['allkids']['child3']['hair'] = ...
```

Is there any way to store this path as a variable so I can access it at my leasure? Obviously

```
mypath = kidshair['allkids']['child3']['hair']
```

results in mypath = 'red'. Is there any possible way to hard code the path itself so I could use:

```
mypath = 'blue'
```

to reperesent

```
kidshair['allkids']['child3']['hair'] = 'blue'
```

Kind thanks, ATfPT

Comment: Check your formatting. `kidshair` will generate a syntax error as it is now.

Comment: This is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797957/python-easily-access-deeply-nested-dict-get-and-set (although not exactly what you're asking)

Comment: @AtheistforPaytheist: It still won't work. 'child1', 'child2', and 'child3' should all be in one dictionary.

Comment: @JoelCornett. Oh lawd, you can tell i'm new to this! I think I have it now.

Comment: @AtheistforPaytheist: Yep. You got it. :)

Comment: You may also consider this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3798595/255008 with code for creating a "dot dictionary".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on what you need, the easiest option may be to use tuples as dictionary keys instead of nested dictionaries:

```
kidshair['allkids', 'child3', 'hair']
mypath = ('allkids', 'child3', 'hair')
kidshair[mypath]
```

The only issue with this is that you can't get a portion of the dictionary, so, for example, you can't (easily/efficiently) access everything to do with `'child3'`. This may or may not be an appropriate solution for you depending on your usage.

An alternative with your current structure is to do something like this:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> test = {"a": {"b": {"c": 1}}}
>>> def itemsetter(item):
...     def f(name, value):
...         item[name] = value
...     return f
...
>>> mypath = partial(itemsetter(test["a"]["b"]), "c")
>>> mypath(2)
>>> test
{'a': {'b': {'c': 2}}}
```

Here we make a function `itemsetter()`, which (in the vein of [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)) gives us a function that that sets the relevant key in the given dictionary. We then use [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to generate a version of this function with the key we want pre-filled. It's not quite `mypath = blue` either, but it's not bad.

If you don't want to bother with making something consistent to the `operator` module, you could simply do:

```
def dictsetter(item, name):
     def f(value):
         item[name] = value
     return f

mypath = dictsetter(test["a"]["b"], "c")

mypath(2)
```

Comment: Brilliantly described, allowed me to more than solve my problem. Sincere thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You could create a set of functions that accesses a 'path' for a given dictionary:

```
def pathGet(dictionary, path):
    for item in path.split("/"):
        dictionary = dictionary[item]
    return dictionary

def pathSet(dictionary, path, setItem):
    path = path.split("/")
    key = path[-1]
    dictionary = pathGet(dictionary, "/".join(path[:-1]))
    dictionary[key] = setItem
```

Usage:

```
>>> pathGet(kidshair, "allkids/child1/hair")
'blonde'
>>> pathSet(kidshair, "allkids/child1/hair", "blue")
>>> kidshair['allkids']['child1']
{'hair': 'blue'}
```

Comment: In retrospect, it's probably easier to pass tuples to 'path' instead of joining and splitting strings.

Comment: I ended up creating similar code before finding this question.  However, as you suggested I created functions that accepted tuples, along with two helper functions that accepted strings and called the path functions with call to split() as the tuple argument.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can do with your current data structure is to get the last dict and use it directly:

```
child = kidshair['allkids']['child3']

child['hair'] = 'blue'
```

This is because in Python, assignment of the style

```
name = value
```

simply binds a new object to the "variable" `name`. There is no way to overload this and the binding can't affect any other object (apart from freeing the object that was bound to this name until now).

On the other hand this:

```
name[key] = value
```

is entirely different because it performs an action (sets an item) on the object currently in `name` (dict in your case).

Answer (score 2):

You can save a reference to `kidshair['allkids']['child3']` easily:

```
thiskid = kidshair['allkids']['child3']
thiskid['hair'] = 'blue'
```

You can't save the entire path, because the assignment changes the `hair` key in the  `kidshair['allkids']['child3']` dictionary.
 If you want to change a dictionary, you must have a reference to it, not to something it contains.

Answer (score 2):

try to use dpath lib https://pypi.org/project/dpath/

```
>>> help(dpath.util.new)
Help on function new in module dpath.util:

new(obj, path, value)
Set the element at the terminus of path to value, and create
it if it does not exist (as opposed to 'set' that can only
change existing keys).

path will NOT be treated like a glob. If it has globbing
characters in it, they will become part of the resulting
keys

>>> dpath.util.new(x, 'a/b/e/f/g', "Roffle")
>>> print json.dumps(x, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "3": 2,
            "43": 30,
            "c": "Waffles",
            "d": "Waffles",
            "e": {
                "f": {
                    "g": "Roffle"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```