# How to set value of dictionary entry by dictionary path?

Tags: python, dictionary, path, tuples

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371732/storing-dictionary-path-in-python) from 2012 provides a (possible) solution where an entry in the dictionary

```py
my_dict = {'allkids':{'child1':{'hair':'blonde'},
                      'child2':{'hair':'black'},
                      'child3':{'hair':'red'},
                      'child4':{'hair':'brown'}}}
```

can be accessed using

```py
mypath = ('allkids', 'child3', 'hair')
kidshair[mypath]
```

However, I get a `KeyError: ('allkids', 'child3', 'hair')` in the `kidshair[mypath]` line when trying this (using Python 3.9.7).

I would like to use a similar solution to set the value of an entry located at a given path. I specifically don't want a function to do that:

```py
kidshair[mypath] = 'black' # this is what I want

set_value(dict=kidshair, path=mypath, value='black') # this is what I don't want

kidshair = set_value(dict=kidshair, path=mypath, value='black') # neither do I want this
```

I need to set the values programmatically. So given a dictionary and a path, how do I perform an operation similar to `my_dict['allkids']['child1']['hair'] = 'Black'`?

Comment: Why not just `kidshair['allkids']['child3']['hair'] = 'yourValue'`?

Comment: @Thijmen yea i don'se see why ```my_dict['allkids']['child1']['hair'] = 'Black'```wont' t work?

Comment: @Thijmen @pyzer Ah, good point. I would like to access the values programmatically. So given a dictionary and a path, how do I perform an operation similar to `my_dict['allkids']['child1']['hair'] = 'Black'`.

Comment: Just use variables instead of strings: `mychild = "child1" myproperty = "hair" my_dict["allkids"][mychild][myproperty] = "Black"`

Comment: Hey thanks for the input. You are right. Somehow I didn't catch the obvious solutions.