# Is there a simple one-liner for accessing each element of a nested dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, dictionary, nested

I often use nested dictionaries in Python 2.7 with 3 or more tiers and use a nested for loop structure, as shown below, to access each element. does anyone know of a simpler, neater or faster method to do so?

```
for foo in mydict:
    for bar in mydict[foo]:
        for etc in mydict[foo][bar]:
            mydict[foo][bar][etc] = "value"
```

Comment: You are not only accessing, but also assigning. So, you want to assign the same value to all the keys of all the nested dictionaries?

Comment: i understand this is a general comment, but i use this method to access, assign, update variables etc. No I dont want to assign the same variable to each key, that could be done easily with many other methods, this is simply about a simple way to iterate over each element, if there is any simpler method than I already use

Comment: This seems to solve your problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797957/python-easily-access-deeply-nested-dict-get-and-set

Comment: Okay cheers, that looks detail heavy, I will have a good read and see what my simple mind can make out of it.

Comment: How does `mydict` look like? Could you post an example?

Comment: As previously mention, mydictdoes not look like anything, it varies between 2 to 5 tiers each usually, but not always with different values, be them either lists, floats or strings. This was just a general inquiry as to methods of iterating over a dictionary, especially in terms of simplicity/readability.

Answer (score 3):

You're using keys to access values. How about using [`dict.itervalues()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) instead?

```
for foo in mydict.itervalues():
    for bar in foo.itervalues():
        for etc in bar: # Iterating a dictionary yields keys
            bar[etc] = "value"
```

Comment: that sounds interesting, I can try to benchmark it and see if it runs any quicker. It simplifies each line a little by removing the successive [], I am wondering if there is anyway to reduce the lines of code though. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the following dictionary:

```
mydict = {'a':{'aa':{'aaa':1}}, 'b':{'bb':{'bbb':2}}, 'c':{'cc':{'ccc':3}}}
```

The code you posted in your example will produce the following result:

```
{'a': {'aa': {'aaa': 'value'}}, 'c': {'cc': {'ccc': 'value'}},
 'b': {'bb': {'bbb': 'value'}}}
```

Since your question also mentions *a one liner* you could use a nested dictionary comprehension but it is not necessarily faster nor neater:

```
mydict = {key:{inner_key:{core_key:'value'
          for core_key in inner_dict.iterkeys()}
          for inner_key, inner_dict in value.iteritems()}
          for key, value in mydict.iteritems()}
```

This will produce the same result as the code you posted.It is technically a one-liner even though for the sake of readability it should not be written in one line.

Comment: ahh! the incomprehensible comprehension method, should really start using them more probably, they just never look as intuitive as a normal for loop, but that could be a good one to play around with. I often have multiple iterations in a script and the ability to put it all on one line can make the script as a whole feel more readable, even if the snippet of code itself is not so nice to read. Thanks