# Python 3 Nested try exceptions for keys in dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, key, try-catch

Is there a good way to handle non-existing dictionary keys?

I have a database based on dictionaries with keys that looks something like this

```
ID
   ver
      sub_ver
           A
           B
           C
```

I want to compare the values for the A, B, C-keys for each ID/ver/sub_ver to assure that:

```
 (A==B and C==None) or (A==C and B==None) or (A==B==C)
```

However not all "IDs" have A and B and C-keys/values

**My not very nice code:**

```
**loops outside of this for ID/ver/sub_ver** 
try:
    A = data_structure[ID][ver][sub_ver]['A']
    B = data_structure[ID][ver][sub_ver]['B']
    C = data_structure[ID][ver][sub_ver]['C']
except KeyError:
    try:
        A = data_structure[ID][ver][sub_ver]['A']
        B = data_structure[ID][ver][sub_ver]['B']
        C = None

    except KeyError: 
        try:
            A = data_structure[ID][ver][sub_ver]['A']
            B = None
            C = data_structure[ID][ver][sub_ver]['C']
```

**Next i check if all values match**

I use set() just in case the A/B/C-lists aren't in order

```
if not any((set(A)==set(B) and C==None, \
            set(A)==set(C) and B==None, \
            set(A)==set(B)==set(C))):
    set_of_problems.append([ID, ver, sub_ver, [A, B, C])
```

Is there a better way to do the nested try/except when it comes to non-existing keys in dictionaries?

Comment: This may be of interest to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797957/python-easily-access-deeply-nested-dict-get-and-set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have too many `try`'s; use `dict.get()` to get optional elements:

```
try:
    A = data_structure[ID][ver][sub_ver]['A']
except KeyError:
    # no A so error, next iteration of your loop
    continue

# we know ID, ver, and sub_ver all are present
B = data_structure[ID][ver][sub_ver].get('B')
C = data_structure[ID][ver][sub_ver].get('C')

if (C is None and A == B) or (B is None and A == C) or (A == B == C):
```

Comment: Ahh .get() that works!
In addition, in order to handle the values being lists i added default values to the get-functions
    .get('B', [None]) 
and changed 
    C is None to C==[None]

Comment: @user2987193: that you need to use `set()` here is a separate issue really; it doesn't have an impact on the original problem and the solution for that problem.