# Applying keys sequentially to a dict from a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm scraping a website, which returns a dictionary:

```
person = {'name0':{'first0': 'John', 'last0':'Smith'},
          'age0':'10',
          'location0':{'city0':'Dublin'}
         }
```

I'm trying to write a function that will return a dictionary `{'name':'John', 'age':'10'}` when passed the above dictionary.

I want to ideally put a `try:... except KeyError` around each item since sometimes keys will be missing.

```
def func(person):
    filters = [('age', 'age0'), ('name', ['name0', 'first0'])]
    result = {'name': None, 'age': None}
    for i in filters:
        try:
            result[i[0]] = person[i[1]]
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return result
```

The problem is `result[i[0]] = person[i[1]]` doesn't work for 'name' since there's two keys that need to be followed sequentially and I don't know how to do that.

I want some way of telling it (in the loop) to go to `person['name0']['first0']` (and so on to whatever depth the thing I want is).

I have lots of things to extract, so I'd rather do it in a loop instead of a `try..except` statement for each variable individually.

Comment: Does [Flatten an irregular (arbitrarily nested) list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-arbitrarily-nested-list-of-lists) answer your question?

Comment: You can use [dict.get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to handle missing keys instead of using try/except.

Comment: Some other ideas: [Nested dictionary value from key path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31033549/nested-dictionary-value-from-key-path).  [Python: Easily access deeply nested dict (get and set)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797957/python-easily-access-deeply-nested-dict-get-and-set).

Comment: Can you supply the website you are trying to scrape?

Answer (score 0):

In order to follow several key sequentially, you can use [get](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-get-method/) and set the default value to `{}` (empty dictionary) for the upper levels. Set the default value to `None` (or whatever suits you) for the last level:

```py
def func(person):
    return {'name': person.get('name0', {}).get('first0', None),
            'age': person.get('age0', None)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best I could manage was using a for loop to iterate through the keys:

```
person = {'name0':{'first0': 'John', 'last0':'Smith'},
          'age0':'10',
          'location0':{'city0':'Dublin'}
         }
```

Additionally I used `.get(key)` rather than `try..except` as suggested by @wiwi

```
def func(person):
    filters = [('age', ['age0']), ('name', ['name0', 'first0'])]
    result = {'name': None, 'age': None}
    for filter in filters:
        temp = person.copy()
        for key in filter[1]:
            temp = temp.get(key)
            if not temp: # NoneType doesn't have .get method
                break
        result[filter[0]] = temp
    return result
```

`func(person)` then returns `{'name': 'John', 'age': '10'}`.

It handles missing input too:

```
person2 = {'age0':'10',
          'location0':{'city0':'Dublin'}}
```

`func(person2)` returns `{'name': None, 'age': '10'}`

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `try...except` in another loop, if there's a list of keys instead of a single key:

```py
def getNestedVal(obj, kPath:list, defaultVal=None):
    if isinstance(kPath, str) or not hasattr(kPath, '__iter__'): 
        kPath = [kPath] ## if not iterable, wrap as list
    for k in kPath: 
        try: obj = obj[k]
        except: return defaultVal
    return obj 

def func(person):
    filters = [('age', 'age0'), ('name', ['name0', 'first0']),#] 
               ('gender', ['gender0'], 'N/A')] # includes default value
    return {k[0]: getNestedVal(person, *k[1:3]) for k in filters}
```

<sup>[I added `gender` just to demonstrate how defaults can also be specified for missing values.]</sup>

With this, `func(person)` should return

> ```py
> {'age': '10', 'name': 'John', 'gender': 'N/A'}
> ```

---

I also have a [`flattenObj`](https://pastebin.com/v3Fep60B) function, a version of which is defined below:

```py
def flattenDict(orig:dict, kList=[], kSep='_', stripNum=True):
    if not isinstance(orig, dict): return [(kList, orig)]

    tList = []
    for k, v in orig.items():
        if isinstance(k, str) and stripNum: k = k.strip('0123456789')
        tList += flattenDict(v, kList+[str(k)], None)
        
    if not isinstance(kSep, str): return tList
    return {kSep.join(kl): v for kl,v in tList}
```

<sup>[I added `stripNum` just to get rid of the `0`s in your keys...]</sup>

`flattenDict(person)` should return

> ```py
> {'name_first': 'John', 'name_last': 'Smith', 'age': '10', 'location_city': 'Dublin'}
> ```