# Accessing dict keys like an attribute?

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax, attributes

I find it more convenient to access dict keys as `obj.foo` instead of `obj['foo']`, so I wrote this snippet:

```
class AttributeDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self[attr]
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        self[attr] = value
```

However, I assume that there must be some reason that Python doesn't provide this functionality out of the box. What would be the caveats and pitfalls of accessing dict keys in this manner?

Comment: If you're accessing hardcoded keys from a fixed-size limited set everywhere, you might be better off creating objects that hold these. `collections.namedtuple` is very useful for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031219/python-recursively-access-dict-via-attributes-as-well-as-index-access has a similar solution but goes a step further

Comment: Found a module for this at https://github.com/bcj/AttrDict. I don't know how it compares to the solutions here and in the related questions.

Comment: I also used similar hacks, now I use `easydict.EasyDict`

Comment: More ways to access dictionary members with a '.' : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352181/how-to-use-a-dot-to-access-members-of-dictionary

Comment: I'd suggest wrapping that return in a try block and adding an exception returning `False`. That way a check like `if (not) dict.key:` can work.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352181/how-to-use-a-dot-to-access-members-of-dictionary

Answer (score 418):

#### Update - 2020

Since this question was asked almost ten years ago, quite a bit has changed in Python itself since then.

While the approach in my original answer is still valid for some cases, (e.g. legacy projects stuck to older versions of Python and cases where you really need to handle dictionaries with very dynamic string keys), I think that in general the [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) introduced in Python 3.7 are the obvious/correct solution to vast majority of the use cases of `AttrDict`.

#### Original answer

The best way to do this is:

```
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self
```

Some pros:

- It actually works!
- No dictionary class methods are shadowed (e.g. `.keys()` work just fine. Unless - of course - you assign some value to them, see below)
- Attributes and items are always in sync
- Trying to access non-existent key as an attribute correctly raises `AttributeError` instead of `KeyError`
- Supports **[Tab]** autocompletion (e.g. in jupyter & ipython)

Cons:

- Methods like `.keys()` will **not** work just fine if they get overwritten by incoming data
- Causes a [memory leak](http://bugs.python.org/issue1469629) in Python < 2.7.4 / Python3 < 3.2.3
- Pylint goes bananas with `E1123(unexpected-keyword-arg)` and `E1103(maybe-no-member)`
- For the uninitiated it seems like pure magic.

#### A short explanation on how this works

- All python objects internally store their attributes in a dictionary that is named `__dict__`.
- There is no requirement that the internal dictionary `__dict__` would need to be "just a plain dict", so we can assign any subclass of `dict()` to the internal dictionary.
- In our case we simply assign the `AttrDict()` instance we are instantiating (as we are in `__init__`).
- By calling `super()`'s `__init__()` method we made sure that it (already) behaves exactly like a dictionary, since that function calls all the *dictionary instantiation* code.

#### One reason why Python doesn't provide this functionality out of the box

As noted in the "cons" list, this combines the namespace of stored keys (which may come from arbitrary and/or untrusted data!) with the namespace of builtin dict method attributes. For example:

```
d = AttrDict()
d.update({'items':["jacket", "necktie", "trousers"]})
for k, v in d.items():    # TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
    print "Never reached!"
```

Comment: Do you think the memorry leak would occur with a simple object like:
   >>> class MyD(object):
   ...     def __init__(self, d):
   ...        self.__dict__ = d

Comment: Causes the leak even in 2.7

Comment: @pi only in < 2.7.3, fixed my answer

Comment: Make that <= 2.7.3, as that's what I am using.

Comment: @Secator You can, but why would you _want_ to do it?

Comment: Another issue to add to the "con" list is that deepcopy doesn't work on it :-(

Comment: In the 2.7.4 release notes they mention it fixed (not before).

Comment: The statement `No dictionary class methods are shadowed (e.g. .keys() work just fine)` doesn't seem to be true for either Python 2.7.10 or Python 3.5.0. Creating a file named `attrdict.py` and running like this: `python -c 'from attrdict import AttrDict; AttrDict(keys="heh").keys()'` gives me the same error for both:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: Added an important caveat to this answer in the "cons" section: if any of the data keys which get put in conflict with existing dict method names, you will get unexpected behavior when you try to use those methods! (This is ± the same thing @jmagnusson is saying in the previous comment.)

Comment: You are correct @natevw  - in my original answer the "Pro" was missing an important sidenote, something along the line - _as in some of the other answers, unless the dictionary contains keys shadowing them_

Comment: How to add a default value for the undefined keys as a defaultdict?

Comment: Is there any way to make the `AttrDict` class protect the build in attributes from what @natevw mentions?

Comment: Have you thought about just using it as a field instead of subclassing it ?

Comment: If i follow that link,  @Yurik what can be done if in case the key in the dict has spaces. obj.foo bar will result in syntax error.

Comment: @viveksinghggits If a value has spaces, you will not be able to use it via AttrDict .dot notation, but you should still be able to get to it via `['...']`

Comment: yes @Yurik, we can use `['...']` but the whole point to use AttriDict is to access through `.` right. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @viveksinghggits just because you are accessing things via the `.`, you cannot break the rules of the language :)  And I wouldn't want `AttrDict` to automagically convert space-containing fields into something different.

Comment: One note: this simple example can't do like: `d.foo.bar`

Comment: I found a case that they're not synchronized. For example, assigns to the `obj.asdfg` didn't change the `obj['asdfg']`

Comment: @Hzzkygcs what version of python? At least in 3.7 that works just fine.

Comment: "Each AttrDict instance actually stores 2 dictionaries, one inherited and another one in __dict__" -- I am not sure I understand this. There is really only one dictionary with an extra reference from `__dict__`. How is this a con? An implementation from ground up could probably avoid the extra reference, but IMHO it hardly matters and so not worth calling out. Am I missing something?

Comment: Good point @haridsv - removed it as it is of "academic interest" at most and is confusing.

Comment: Can't you add if `if` statement on each insert that prevents this

Answer (score 128):

You can have all legal string characters as part of the key if you use array notation.
For example, `obj['!#$%^&*()_']`

Comment: @Izkata yes. funny thing about SE that there is usually a 'top question' ie. title, and a 'bottom question', perhaps because SE doesn't like to hear "title says it all"; the 'caveats' being the bottom one here.

Comment: Not that JavaScript is a particularly good example of programming language, but objects in JS support both attribute access and array notation, which allows convenience for the common case *and* a generic fallback for symbols that aren't legal attribute names.

Comment: @Izkata How does this answer the question. This answer just says that keys can have any name.

Comment: @Melab The question is `What would be the caveats and pitfalls of accessing dict keys in this manner?` (as attributes), and the answer is that most of the characters shown here would not be useable.

Answer (score 97):

## Wherein I Answer the Question That Was Asked

### Why doesn't Python offer it out of the box?

I suspect that it has to do with the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): "There should be one -- and preferably only one -- obvious way to do it."  This would create two obvious ways to access values from dictionaries: `obj['key']` and `obj.key`.

### Caveats and Pitfalls

These include possible lack of clarity and confusion in the code.  i.e., the following could be confusing to someone **else** who is going in to maintain your code at a later date, or even to you, if you're not going back into it for awhile.  Again, from [Zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): "Readability counts!"

```
>>> KEY = 'spam'
>>> d[KEY] = 1
>>> # Several lines of miscellaneous code here...
... assert d.spam == 1
```

If `d` is instantiated **or** `KEY` is defined **or** `d[KEY]` is assigned far away from where `d.spam` is being used, it can easily lead to confusion about what's being done, since this isn't a commonly-used idiom.  I know it would have the potential to confuse me.

Additonally, if you change the value of `KEY` as follows (but miss changing `d.spam`), you now get:

```
>>> KEY = 'foo'
>>> d[KEY] = 1
>>> # Several lines of miscellaneous code here...
... assert d.spam == 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'spam'
```

IMO, not worth the effort.

### Other Items

As others have noted, you can use any hashable object (not just a string) as a dict key.  For example,

```
>>> d = {(2, 3): True,}
>>> assert d[(2, 3)] is True
>>>
```

is legal, but

```
>>> C = type('C', (object,), {(2, 3): True})
>>> d = C()
>>> assert d.(2, 3) is True
  File "<stdin>", line 1
  d.(2, 3)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> getattr(d, (2, 3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string
>>>
```

is not.  This gives you access to the entire range of printable characters or other hashable objects for your dictionary keys, which you do not have when accessing an object attribute.  This makes possible such magic as a cached object metaclass, like the recipe from the [Python Cookbook (Ch. 9)](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch09.html#_solution_156).

## Wherein I Editorialize

I prefer the aesthetics of `spam.eggs` over `spam['eggs']` (I think it looks cleaner), and I really started craving this functionality when I met the [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).  But the convenience of being able to do the following trumps it.

```
>>> KEYS = 'spam eggs ham'
>>> VALS = [1, 2, 3]
>>> d = {k: v for k, v in zip(KEYS.split(' '), VALS)}
>>> assert d == {'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'ham': 3}
>>>
```

This is a simple example, but I frequently find myself using dicts in different situations than I'd use `obj.key` notation (i.e., when I need to read prefs in from an XML file).  In other cases, where I'm tempted to instantiate a dynamic class and slap some attributes on it for aesthetic reasons, I continue to use a dict for consistency in order to enhance readability.

I'm sure the OP has long-since resolved this to his satisfaction, but if he still wants this functionality, then I suggest he download one of the packages from pypi that provides it:

- <s>**[Bunch](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bunch/1.0.1)** is the one I'm more familiar with.  Subclass of `dict`, so you have all that functionality.</s>
- <s>**[AttrDict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/attrdict/1.2.0)** also looks like it's also pretty good, but I'm not as familiar with it and haven't looked through the source in as much detail as I have [Bunch](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bunch/1.0.1).</s>
- **[Addict](https://github.com/mewwts/addict)** Is actively maintained and provides attr-like access and more.
- As noted in the comments by Rotareti, Bunch has been deprecated, but there is an active fork called **[Munch](https://github.com/Infinidat/munch)**.

However, in order to improve readability of his code I strongly recommend that he **not** mix his notation styles.  If he prefers this notation then he should simply instantiate a dynamic object, add his desired attributes to it, and call it a day:

```
>>> C = type('C', (object,), {})
>>> d = C()
>>> d.spam = 1
>>> d.eggs = 2
>>> d.ham = 3
>>> assert d.__dict__ == {'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'ham': 3}
```

---

## Wherein I Update, to Answer a Follow-Up Question in the Comments

In the comments (below), **Elmo** asks:

> What if you want to go one deeper? ( referring to type(...) )

While I've never used this use case (again, I tend to use nested `dict`, for
consistency), the following code works:

```
>>> C = type('C', (object,), {})
>>> d = C()
>>> for x in 'spam eggs ham'.split():
...     setattr(d, x, C())
...     i = 1
...     for y in 'one two three'.split():
...         setattr(getattr(d, x), y, i)
...         i += 1
...
>>> assert d.spam.__dict__ == {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
```

Comment: *Bunch* is deprecated, but there is an active fork of it:  https://github.com/Infinidat/munch

Comment: @Rotareti - Thanks for the heads-up!  This isn't functionality I use, so I was unaware of that.

Comment: What if you want to go one deeper? ( referring to type(...) )

Comment: Python is like an inverted umbrella held high in heavy rain. It all looks smart and funky to begin with, after some time it begins to get heavy, then suddenly, you read some built-ins guru stuff on SE and the entire thing reverts back with the entire payload down your shoulders. While still drenched you feel lighter and everything is so clear and refreshed.

Comment: Thanks for providing alternatives to AttrDict which no longer works with Python 3.10

Comment: @Dominik - I was unaware of [Addict](https://github.com/mewwts/addict). Credit to Piotr Dabkowski for adding that one in an edit.

Answer (score 91):

From [This other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021041/are-there-any-gotchas-with-this-python-pattern) there's a great implementation example that simplifies your existing code.  How about:

```
class AttributeDict(dict):
    __slots__ = () 
    __getattr__ = dict.__getitem__
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
```

Much more concise and doesn't leave any room for extra cruft getting into your `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` functions in the future.

Comment: Would you be able to call AttributeDict.update or AttributeDict.get using this method?

Comment: +1 because it works perfectly as far as I can tell.  @GringoSuave, @Izkata, @P3trus I request anyone claiming it fails show an example that doesn’t work
`d = AttributeDict(foo=1);d.bar = 1;print d` => `{'foo': 1, 'bar': 1}`
Works for me!

Comment: It's been 8 months so I don't remember unfortunately.  But, a quick test shows it doesn't work for me under Py 2.6/Windows, yet it does under 2.7/Linux.

Comment: @P3trus runtime assignments are added to the instance's `__dict__` attribute (not `dict`), to be exact. For example, instance is `d = AttributeDict()` and they are added to `d.__dict__`. I guess you meant that but suffered a comment formatting problem.

Comment: @DaveAbrahams Did the test on 2.7 x32 on Windows 7 x64 and it is at P3trus says here.

Comment: @DaveAbrahams Read the _full_ question and look at answers by Hery, Ryan, and TheCommunistDuck.  It's not asking about _how_ to do this, but about _problems that may arise_.

Comment: You should provide a `__getattr__` method that raises an `AttributeError` if the given attribute doesn't exist, otherwise things like `getattr(obj, attr, default_value)` do not work (i.e. doesn't return `default_value` if `attr` doesn't exist on `obj`)

Comment: Causes `KeyError: '__getstate__'` from `pickle.dump`.

Comment: In Python3, the following raises a `KeyError`, whereas one would desire `False`: `d = AttributeDict(); hasattr(d, 'foo')`. As others have proposed, the solution is to convert the KeyError into an AttributeErrror inside `__getattr__` as done e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48806603).

Answer (score 33):

You can pull a convenient container class from the standard library:

```
from argparse import Namespace
```

to avoid having to copy around code bits. No standard dictionary access, but easy to get one back if you really want it. The code in argparse is simple,

```
class Namespace(_AttributeHolder):
    """Simple object for storing attributes.

    Implements equality by attribute names and values, and provides a simple
    string representation.
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for name in kwargs:
            setattr(self, name, kwargs[name])

    __hash__ = None

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return vars(self) == vars(other)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not (self == other)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self.__dict__
```

Comment: PLUS 1 for referencing a standard library, which addresses the first comment by the OP.

Comment: Python includes a faster class (implemented in C) for that case: `types.SimpleNamespace` https://docs.python.org/dev/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace

Comment: Just to make it clear: if `d` is your dictionary, `o = Namespace(**d)` would contain the desired object :)

Answer (score 24):

Caveat emptor: For some reasons classes like this seem to break the multiprocessing package.  I just struggled with this bug for awhile before finding this SO: 
[Finding exception in python multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819447/finding-exception-in-python-multiprocessing)

Answer (score 24):

I found myself wondering what the current state of "dict keys as attr" in the python ecosystem. As several commenters have pointed out, this is probably **not something you want to roll your own from scratch**, as there are several pitfalls and footguns, some of them very subtle. Also, I would not recommend using `Namespace` as a base class, I've been down that road, it isn't pretty.

Fortunately, there are several open source packages providing this functionality, ready to pip install! Unfortunately, there are several packages. Here is a synopsis, as of Dec 2019.

Contenders (most recent commit to master|#commits|#contribs|coverage%):

- [addict](https://github.com/mewwts/addict)   (2021-01-05 | 229 | 22 | 100%)
- [munch](https://github.com/Infinidat/munch) (2021-01-22 | 166 | 17 | ?%)
- [easydict](https://github.com/makinacorpus/easydict) (2021-02-28 | 54 | 7 | ?%)
- [attrdict](https://github.com/bcj/AttrDict) (2019-02-01 | 108 | 5 | 100%)
- [prodict](https://github.com/ramazanpolat/prodict)  (2021-03-06 | 100 | 2 | ?%)

No longer maintained or under-maintained:

- [treedict](https://github.com/hoytak/treedict) (2014-03-28 | 95 | 2 | ?%)
- [bunch](https://github.com/dsc/bunch) (2012-03-12 | 20 | 2 | ?%)
- NeoBunch

I currently recommend **munch** or **addict**. They have the most commits, contributors, and releases, suggesting a healthy open-source codebase for each. They have the cleanest-looking readme.md, 100% coverage, and good looking set of tests.

I do not have a dog in this race (for now!), besides having rolled my own dict/attr code and wasted a ton of time because I was not aware of all these options :). I may contribute to addict/munch in the future as I would rather see one solid package than a bunch of fragmented ones. If you like them, contribute! In particular, looks like munch could use a codecov badge and addict could use a python version badge.

**addict pros:**

- recursive initialization (foo.a.b.c = 'bar'), dict-like arguments become addict.Dict

**addict cons:**

- shadows `typing.Dict` if you `from addict import Dict`
- No key checking. Due to allowing recursive init, if you misspell a key, you just create a new attribute, rather than KeyError (thanks  AljoSt)

**munch pros:**

- unique naming
- built-in ser/de functions for JSON and YAML

**munch cons:**

- no recursive init (you cannot construct `foo.a.b.c = 'bar'`, you must set `foo.a`, then `foo.a.b`, etc.

## Wherein I Editorialize

Many moons ago, when I used text editors to write python, on projects with only myself or one other dev, I liked the style of dict-attrs, the ability to insert keys by just declaring `foo.bar.spam = eggs`. Now I work on teams, and use an IDE for everything, and I have drifted away from these sorts of data structures and dynamic typing in general, in favor of static analysis, functional techniques and type hints. I've started experimenting with this technique, subclassing Pstruct with objects of my own design:

```py
class  BasePstruct(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self.__slots__:
            return self[name]
        return self.__getattribute__(name)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key in self.__slots__:
            self[key] = value
            return
        if key in type(self).__dict__:
            self[key] = value
            return
        raise AttributeError(
            "type object '{}' has no attribute '{}'".format(type(self).__name__, key))


class FooPstruct(BasePstruct):
    __slots__ = ['foo', 'bar']
```

This gives you an object which still behaves like a dict, but also lets you access keys like attributes, in a much more rigid fashion. The advantage here is I (or the hapless consumers of your code) know exactly what fields can and can't exist, and the IDE can autocomplete fields. Also subclassing vanilla `dict` means json serialization is easy. I think the next evolution in this idea would be a custom protobuf generator which emits these interfaces, and a nice knock-on is you get cross-language data structures and IPC via gRPC for nearly free.

If you do decide to go with attr-dicts, it's essential to document what fields are expected, for your own (and your teammates') sanity.

Feel free to edit/update this post to keep it recent!

Comment: a big con for `addict` is that it will not raise exceptions when you misspell an attribute, as it will return a new `Dict` (this is necessary for foo.a.b.c = 'bar' to work).

Comment: What do you mean with the munch cons "no recursive init / only can init one attr at a time"? Could you please give an example?

Comment: @MartinThoma - You cannot do something like `m = Munch(); m.hi.ho = 'silver'`, you get `AttributeError: hi` because `m.hi` has not been assigned yet.

Answer (score 18):

What if you wanted a key which was a method, such as `__eq__` or `__getattr__`?

And you wouldn't be able to have an entry that didn't start with a letter, so using `0343853` as a key is out.

And what if you didn't want to use a string?

Comment: Indeed, or for example other objects as keys. However I would classify the error from that as 'expected behaviour' - with my question I was more aiming towards the unexpected.

Comment: `pickle.dump` uses `__getstate__`

Answer (score 13):

tuples can be used dict keys. How would you access tuple in your construct?

Also, [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) is a convenient structure which can provide values via the attribute access.

Comment: The drawback of namedtuples is that they are immutable.

Comment: Some would say that being immutable is not a bug but a feature of tuples.

Answer (score 11):

How about [Prodict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/prodict/), the little Python class that [I wrote](https://github.com/ramazanpolat/prodict) to rule them all:)

Plus, you get **auto code completion**, **recursive object instantiations** and **auto type conversion**!

You can do exactly what you asked for:

```
p = Prodict()
p.foo = 1
p.bar = "baz"
```

## Example 1: Type hinting

```
class Country(Prodict):
    name: str
    population: int

turkey = Country()
turkey.name = 'Turkey'
turkey.population = 79814871
```

[image: auto code complete]

## Example 2: Auto type conversion

```
germany = Country(name='Germany', population='82175700', flag_colors=['black', 'red', 'yellow'])

print(germany.population)  # 82175700
print(type(germany.population))  # <class 'int'>

print(germany.flag_colors)  # ['black', 'red', 'yellow']
print(type(germany.flag_colors))  # <class 'list'>
```

Comment: installs on python2 via pip, but doesn't work on python2

Comment: @Ant6n requires python 3.6+ because of type annotations

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't work in generality.  Not all valid dict keys make addressable attributes ("the key").  So, you'll need to be careful.

Python objects are all basically dictionaries.  So I doubt there is much performance or other penalty.

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't address the original question, but should be useful for people that, like me, end up here when looking for a lib that provides this functionality.

**Addict** it's a great lib for this: https://github.com/mewwts/addict it takes care of many concerns mentioned in previous answers.

An example from the docs:

```
body = {
    'query': {
        'filtered': {
            'query': {
                'match': {'description': 'addictive'}
            },
            'filter': {
                'term': {'created_by': 'Mats'}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With addict:

```
from addict import Dict
body = Dict()
body.query.filtered.query.match.description = 'addictive'
body.query.filtered.filter.term.created_by = 'Mats'
```

Answer (score 7):

Just to add some variety to the answer, [sci-kit learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a805efbe4bb06516670a9b8c690992bd7/sklearn/utils/__init__.py#L31) has this implemented as a `Bunch`:

```
class Bunch(dict):                                                              
    """ Scikit Learn's container object                                         

    Dictionary-like object that exposes its keys as attributes.                 
    >>> b = Bunch(a=1, b=2)                                                     
    >>> b['b']                                                                  
    2                                                                           
    >>> b.b                                                                     
    2                                                                           
    >>> b.c = 6                                                                 
    >>> b['c']                                                                  
    6                                                                           
    """                                                                         

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):                                               
        super(Bunch, self).__init__(kwargs)                                     

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):                                          
        self[key] = value                                                       

    def __dir__(self):                                                          
        return self.keys()                                                      

    def __getattr__(self, key):                                                 
        try:                                                                    
            return self[key]                                                    
        except KeyError:                                                        
            raise AttributeError(key)                                           

    def __setstate__(self, state):                                              
        pass
```

All you need is to get the `setattr` and `getattr` methods - the `getattr` checks for dict keys and the moves on to checking for actual attributes. The `setstaet` is a fix for fix for pickling/unpickling "bunches" - if inerested check https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6196

Answer (score 7):

After not being satisfied with the existing options for the reasons below I developed [MetaDict](https://github.com/LarsHill/metadict). It behaves exactly like `dict` but enables dot notation and IDE autocompletion without the shortcomings and potential namespace conflicts of other solutions. All features and usage examples can be found on GitHub (see link above).

Full disclosure: I am the author of [MetaDict](https://github.com/LarsHill/metadict).

Shortcomings/limitations I encountered when trying out other solutions:

- [Addict](https://github.com/mewwts/addict)

  - No key autocompletion in IDE
  - Nested key assignment cannot be turned off
  - Newly assigned `dict` objects are not converted to support attribute-style key access
  - Shadows inbuilt type `Dict`
- [Prodict](https://github.com/ramazanpolat/prodict)

  - No key autocompletion in IDE without defining a static schema (similar to `dataclass`)
  - No recursive conversion of `dict` objects when embedded in `list` or other inbuilt iterables
- [AttrDict](https://github.com/bcj/AttrDict)

  - No key autocompletion in IDE
  - Converts `list` objects to `tuple` behind the scenes
- [Munch](https://github.com/Infinidat/munch)

  - Inbuilt methods like `items()`, `update()`, etc. can be overwritten with `obj.items = [1, 2, 3]`
  - No recursive conversion of `dict` objects when embedded in `list` or other inbuilt iterables
- [EasyDict](https://github.com/makinacorpus/easydict)

  - Only strings are valid keys, but `dict` accepts all hashable objects as keys
  - Inbuilt methods like `items()`, `update()`, etc. can be overwritten with `obj.items = [1, 2, 3]`
  - Inbuilt methods don't behave as expected: `obj.pop('unknown_key', None)` raises an `AttributeError`

Comment: nice, but unfortunately I don't get autocompletion when I pass in a `dict`, at least in Pycharm. It's very likely just Pycharm not supporting a generally supported feature, though.

Comment: Autocompletion only works when the `MetaDict` object is loaded in the RAM, e.g. in PyCharm's interactive debugger or in an open Python session. The screenshot from the autocompletion feature in the [README](https://github.com/LarsHill/metadict) is from PyCharm's Python console.

Also, only dict keys that comply the python variable syntax are accessible via dot notation and thus, suggested via the autocompletion feature of the IDE.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Do you see the builtin methods (e.g. `items()`, `keys()`, etc.) as suggestions via autocompletion in the interactive python session? If not I suspect a PyCharm issue. Maybe a restart resolves it?

Comment: How would you rate Pydantic?

Comment: @AndrewMellinger Pydantic is amazing, given you can define a static data model. This library does not try to replace pydantic or data classes but simply allows you to use the inbuilt dict with Attribute syntax.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace):

```py
from types import SimpleNamespace

obj = SimpleNamespace(color="blue", year=2050)

print(obj.color) #> "blue"
print(obj.year) #> 2050
```

EDIT / UPDATE: a closer answer to the OP's question, starting from a dictionary:

```py
from types import SimpleNamespace

params = {"color":"blue", "year":2020}

obj = SimpleNamespace(**params)

print(obj.color) #> "blue"
print(obj.year) #> 2050
```

Comment: Just for the record, `SimpleNamespace` is available since Python 3.3.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in modern python.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a short example of immutable records using built-in [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
def record(name, d):
    return namedtuple(name, d.keys())(**d)
```

and a usage example:

```
rec = record('Model', {
    'train_op': train_op,
    'loss': loss,
})

print rec.loss(..)
```

Answer (score 4):

Apparently there is now a library for this - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/attrdict - which implements this exact functionality plus recursive merging and json loading. Might be worth a look.

Comment: Minor downside: It won't pretty-print in iPython.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using this class I just made. With this class you can use the `Map` object like another dictionary(including json serialization) or with the dot notation. I hope help you:

```
class Map(dict):
    """
    Example:
    m = Map({'first_name': 'Eduardo'}, last_name='Pool', age=24, sports=['Soccer'])
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Map, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for arg in args:
            if isinstance(arg, dict):
                for k, v in arg.iteritems():
                    self[k] = v

        if kwargs:
            for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
                self[k] = v

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.get(attr)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.__setitem__(key, value)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super(Map, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        self.__dict__.update({key: value})

    def __delattr__(self, item):
        self.__delitem__(item)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        super(Map, self).__delitem__(key)
        del self.__dict__[key]
```

**Usage examples:**

```
m = Map({'first_name': 'Eduardo'}, last_name='Pool', age=24, sports=['Soccer'])
# Add new key
m.new_key = 'Hello world!'
print m.new_key
print m['new_key']
# Update values
m.new_key = 'Yay!'
# Or
m['new_key'] = 'Yay!'
# Delete key
del m.new_key
# Or
del m['new_key']
```

Comment: Note that it can shadow `dict` methods, e.g.: `m=Map(); m["keys"] = 42; m.keys()` gives `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`.

Comment: @bfontaine The idea is to be a kind of `field/attribute` and not a `method`, but if you assign a method instead a number you can access that method with `m.method()`.

Answer (score 4):

Let me post another implementation, which builds upon the answer of Kinvais, but integrates ideas from the AttributeDict proposed in http://databio.org/posts/python_AttributeDict.html.

The advantage of this version is that it also works for nested dictionaries:

```
class AttrDict(dict):
    """
    A class to convert a nested Dictionary into an object with key-values
    that are accessible using attribute notation (AttrDict.attribute) instead of
    key notation (Dict["key"]). This class recursively sets Dicts to objects,
    allowing you to recurse down nested dicts (like: AttrDict.attr.attr)
    """

    # Inspired by:
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/14620633/1551810
    # http://databio.org/posts/python_AttributeDict.html

    def __init__(self, iterable, **kwargs):
        super(AttrDict, self).__init__(iterable, **kwargs)
        for key, value in iterable.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                self.__dict__[key] = AttrDict(value)
            else:
                self.__dict__[key] = value
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what I use

```
args = {
        'batch_size': 32,
        'workers': 4,
        'train_dir': 'train',
        'val_dir': 'val',
        'lr': 1e-3,
        'momentum': 0.9,
        'weight_decay': 1e-4
    }
args = namedtuple('Args', ' '.join(list(args.keys())))(**args)

print (args.lr)
```

Comment: This is a good quick and dirty answer. My only observation/comment is that I think the namedtuple constructor will accept a list of strings, so your solution can be simplified (I think) to: `namedtuple('Args', list(args.keys()))(**args)`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to define a class let's call it Namespace. which uses the object **dict**.update() on the dict. Then, the dict will be treated as an object.

```
class Namespace(object):
    '''
    helps referencing object in a dictionary as dict.key instead of dict['key']
    '''
    def __init__(self, adict):
        self.__dict__.update(adict)



Person = Namespace({'name': 'ahmed',
                     'age': 30}) #--> added for edge_cls


print(Person.name)
```

Comment: Amazing - the best, most concise answer buried way down at the bottom and it took almost 10 years for it to appear. Thanks!

Comment: but, not print easy like dict: `str` or `repr` got `<__main__.Namespace object at 0x7f6f5b1004f0>`

Answer (score 3):

No need to write your own as
[setattr()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr) and getattr() already exist.

The advantage of class objects probably comes into play in class definition and inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

I created this based on the input from this thread. I need to use odict though, so I had to override get and set attr. I think this should work for the majority of special uses.

Usage looks like this:

```
# Create an ordered dict normally...
>>> od = OrderedAttrDict()
>>> od["a"] = 1
>>> od["b"] = 2
>>> od
OrderedAttrDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])

# Get and set data using attribute access...
>>> od.a
1
>>> od.b = 20
>>> od
OrderedAttrDict([('a', 1), ('b', 20)])

# Setting a NEW attribute only creates it on the instance, not the dict...
>>> od.c = 8
>>> od
OrderedAttrDict([('a', 1), ('b', 20)])
>>> od.c
8
```

The class:

```
class OrderedAttrDict(odict.OrderedDict):
    """
    Constructs an odict.OrderedDict with attribute access to data.

    Setting a NEW attribute only creates it on the instance, not the dict.
    Setting an attribute that is a key in the data will set the dict data but 
    will not create a new instance attribute
    """
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        """
        Try to get the data. If attr is not a key, fall-back and get the attr
        """
        if self.has_key(attr):
            return super(OrderedAttrDict, self).__getitem__(attr)
        else:
            return super(OrderedAttrDict, self).__getattr__(attr)


    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        """
        Try to set the data. If attr is not a key, fall-back and set the attr
        """
        if self.has_key(attr):
            super(OrderedAttrDict, self).__setitem__(attr, value)
        else:
            super(OrderedAttrDict, self).__setattr__(attr, value)
```

This is a pretty cool pattern already mentioned in the thread, but if you just want to take a dict and convert it to an object that works with auto-complete in an IDE, etc:

```
class ObjectFromDict(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.__dict__ = d
```

Answer (score 3):

this answer is taken from the book Fluent Python by Luciano Ramalho. so credits to that guy.

```
class AttrDict:
    """A read-only façade for navigating a JSON-like object
    using attribute notation
    """

    def __init__(self, mapping):
        self._data = dict(mapping)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if hasattr(self._data, name):
            return getattr(self._data, name)
        else:
            return AttrDict.build(self._data[name])

    @classmethod
    def build(cls, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Mapping):
            return cls(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, MutableSequence):
            return [cls.build(item) for item in obj]
        else:
            return obj
```

in the init we are taking the dict and making it a dictionary. when getattr is used we try to get the attribute from the dict if the dict already has that attribute. or else we are passing the argument to a class method called build. now build does the intresting thing. if the object is dict or a mapping like that, the that object is made an attr dict itself. if it's a sequence like list, it's passed to the build function we r on right now. if it's anythin else, like str or int. return the object itself.

Answer (score 2):

Solution is:

```
DICT_RESERVED_KEYS = vars(dict).keys()


class SmartDict(dict):
    """
    A Dict which is accessible via attribute dot notation
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        :param args: multiple dicts ({}, {}, ..)
        :param kwargs: arbitrary keys='value'

        If ``keyerror=False`` is passed then not found attributes will
        always return None.
        """
        super(SmartDict, self).__init__()
        self['__keyerror'] = kwargs.pop('keyerror', True)
        [self.update(arg) for arg in args if isinstance(arg, dict)]
        self.update(kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr not in DICT_RESERVED_KEYS:
            if self['__keyerror']:
                return self[attr]
            else:
                return self.get(attr)
        return getattr(self, attr)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key in DICT_RESERVED_KEYS:
            raise AttributeError("You cannot set a reserved name as attribute")
        self.__setitem__(key, value)

    def __copy__(self):
        return self.__class__(self)

    def copy(self):
        return self.__copy__()
```

Answer (score 2):

> What would be the caveats and pitfalls of accessing dict keys in this manner?

As @Henry suggests, one reason dotted-access may not be used in dicts is that it limits dict key names to python-valid variables, thereby restricting all possible names.

The following are examples on why dotted-access would not be helpful in general, given a dict, `d`:

*Validity*

The following attributes would be invalid in Python:

```
d.1_foo                           # enumerated names
d./bar                            # path names
d.21.7, d.12:30                   # decimals, time
d.""                              # empty strings
d.john doe, d.denny's             # spaces, misc punctuation 
d.3 * x                           # expressions
```

*Style*

PEP8 conventions would impose a soft constraint on attribute naming:

A.  Reserved [keyword](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments) (or builtin function) names:

```
d.in
d.False, d.True
d.max, d.min
d.sum
d.id
```

> If a function argument's name clashes with a reserved keyword, it is generally better to append a single trailing underscore ...

B. The case rule on [methods](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) and [variable names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names):

> Variable names follow the same convention as function names.

```
d.Firstname
d.Country
```

> Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

---

Sometimes these concerns are raised in [libraries like pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757090/pandas-column-access-w-column-names-containing-spaces), which permits dotted-access of DataFrame columns by name.  The default mechanism to resolve naming restrictions is also array-notation - a string within brackets.

If these constraints do not apply to your use case, there are several options on [dotted-access data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47784683/4531270).

Comment: I just ran into this problem with Pandas object.attribute dot notation.  The syntax gets ugly with object.attribute notation when doing pandas filters.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to add one more, but this one addresses the subdicts and correct AttributeError, although being very simple:

```
class DotDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, d: dict = {}):
        super().__init__()
        for key, value in d.items():
            self[key] = DotDict(value) if type(value) is dict else value
    
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key in self:
            return self[key]
        raise AttributeError(key) #Set proper exception, not KeyError

    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a 'good' answer, but I thought this was nifty (it doesn't handle nested dicts in current form). Simply wrap your dict in a function:

```
def make_funcdict(d=None, **kwargs)
    def funcdict(d=None, **kwargs):
        if d is not None:
            funcdict.__dict__.update(d)
        funcdict.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        return funcdict.__dict__
    funcdict(d, **kwargs)
    return funcdict
```

Now you have slightly different syntax. To acces the dict items as attributes do `f.key`. To access the dict items (and other dict methods) in the usual manner do `f()['key']` and we can conveniently update the dict by calling f with keyword arguments and/or a dictionary

### Example

```
d = {'name':'Henry', 'age':31}
d = make_funcdict(d)
>>> for key in d():
...     print key
... 
age
name
>>> print d.name
... Henry
>>> print d.age
... 31
>>> d({'Height':'5-11'}, Job='Carpenter')
... {'age': 31, 'name': 'Henry', 'Job': 'Carpenter', 'Height': '5-11'}
```

And there it is. I'll be happy if anyone suggests benefits and drawbacks of this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
class AttrDict(dict):

     def __init__(self):
           self.__dict__ = self

if __name__ == '____main__':

     d = AttrDict()
     d['ray'] = 'hope'
     d.sun = 'shine'  >>> Now we can use this . notation
     print d['ray']
     print d.sun
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dict_to_obj
https://pypi.org/project/dict-to-obj/ 
It does exactly what you asked for

```py
From dict_to_obj import DictToObj
a = {
'foo': True
}
b = DictToObj(a)
b.foo
True
```

Comment: It is good form to put `.idea` and any user-specific or IDE generated files in your `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** NeoBunch is depricated, Munch (mentioned above) can be used as a drop-in replacement. I leave that solution here though, it can be useful for someone.

As noted by Doug there's a Bunch package which you can use to achieve the `obj.key` functionality. Actually there's a newer version called

<s>[NeoBunch](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/neobunch)</s> **[Munch](https://github.com/Infinidat/munch)**

It has though a great feature converting your dict to a NeoBunch object through its *neobunchify* function. I use Mako templates a lot and passing data as NeoBunch objects makes them far more readable, so if you happen to end up using a normal dict in your Python program but want the dot notation in a Mako template you can use it that way:

```
from mako.template import Template
from neobunch import neobunchify

mako_template = Template(filename='mako.tmpl', strict_undefined=True)
data = {'tmpl_data': [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}]}
with open('out.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write(mako_template.render(**neobunchify(data)))
```

And the Mako template could look like:

```
% for d in tmpl_data:
Column1     Column2
${d.key1}   ${d.key2}
% endfor
```

Comment: Link to NeoBunch is 404

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like to thank @Kimvais for his genius answer.
I added some stuff to it.

Create a file, called **punktdict.py**

```
import sys

dictconfig = sys.modules[__name__]
# Create a reference to the current module's `sys.modules` dictionary,
# which allows accessing and modifying the configuration options.

dictconfig.allow_nested_attribute_creation = True
# Set the configuration option `allow_nested_attribute_creation` to True,
# allowing the creation of nested attributes in PunktDict objects.

dictconfig.allow_nested_key_creation = True
# Set the configuration option `allow_nested_key_creation` to True,
# allowing the creation of nested keys in PunktDict objects.

dictconfig.convert_all_dicts_recursively = True
# Set the configuration option `convert_all_dicts_recursively` to True,
# enabling recursive conversion of all nested dictionaries in PunktDict objects.


def check_if_compatible_dict(di, class_):
    """
    Check if the provided object is a compatible dictionary based on its type and attributes.

    Args:
    - di: The object to check for compatibility.
    - class_: The class representing the compatible dictionary type.

    Returns:
    - True if the object is a compatible dictionary, False otherwise.


    """
    return (isinstance(di, dict) and not isinstance(di, class_)) or (
        (hasattr(di, "items") and hasattr(di, "keys") and hasattr(di, "values"))
    )


def convert_to_dict(di):
    """
    Recursively converts a PunktDict object or a compatible dictionary to a regular dictionary.

    Args:
    - di: The PunktDict object or compatible dictionary to convert.

    Returns:
    - The converted regular dictionary.
    """
    if isinstance(di, dict) or (
        hasattr(di, "items") and hasattr(di, "keys") and hasattr(di, "values")
    ):
        di = {k: convert_to_dict(v) for k, v in di.items()}
    return di


class PunktDict(dict):
    """
    A subclass of dict with additional functionality for handling nested dictionaries.

    Overrides some methods and provides additional methods to handle nested dictionaries.

    Attributes:
    - allow_nested_attribute_creation: A boolean flag indicating whether PunktDict allows creation of nested attributes.
    - allow_nested_key_creation: A boolean flag indicating whether PunktDict allows creation of nested keys.
    - convert_all_dicts_recursively: A boolean flag indicating whether PunktDict recursively converts all nested dictionaries to PunktDict objects.

    Methods:
    - __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): Initializes a new PunktDict object.
    - __setitem__(self, key, value): Sets an item in the PunktDict.
    - __missing__(self, key): Handles missing key access in the PunktDict.
    - update(self, *args, **kwargs): Updates the PunktDict with new data.
    - _check_forbidden_key(self, *args, **kwargs): Checks if a key is forbidden.
    - __getattr__(self, item): Handles attribute access in the PunktDict.


    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Initializes a new PunktDict object.

        Args:
        - *args: Variable length argument list.
        - **kwargs: Arbitrary keyword arguments.

        Notes:
        - Converts all nested dictionaries in the PunktDict object to PunktDict objects
          if the `convert_all_dicts_recursively` option is enabled.
        - Maps the PunktDict object itself to its `__dict__` attribute.
        """

        def convert_dict(di):
            """
            Recursively converts a compatible dictionary to a PunktDict object.

            Args:
            - di: The compatible dictionary to convert.

            Returns:
            - The converted PunktDict object.
            """
            if check_if_compatible_dict(di, self.__class__):
                ndi = self.__class__({})
                for k, v in di.items():
                    ndi[k] = convert_dict(v)
                return ndi
            return di

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if dictconfig.convert_all_dicts_recursively:
            for key in self:
                if key not in dir(dict):
                    self[key] = convert_dict(self[key])
        self.__dict__ = self

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        """
        Sets an item in the PunktDict.

        Args:
        - key: The key to set.
        - value: The value to assign to the key.

        Notes:
        - Converts the value to a PunktDict object if it is a compatible dictionary
          and the `convert_all_dicts_recursively` option is enabled.
        - Raises a ValueError if the key is not allowed.
        """
        if dictconfig.convert_all_dicts_recursively:
            if check_if_compatible_dict(value, self.__class__):
                value = self.__class__(value)
        if key not in dir(dict):
            super().__setitem__(key, value)
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'Key "{key}" not allowed!')

    def __missing__(self, key):
        """
        Handles missing key access in the PunktDict.

        Args:
        - key: The missing key.

        Returns:
        - The created nested PunktDict if `allow_nested_key_creation` is enabled.

        Raises:
        - KeyError: If `allow_nested_key_creation` is disabled and the key is not found.
        """
        if dictconfig.allow_nested_key_creation:
            self[key] = self.__class__({})
            return self[key]
        raise KeyError(f'"{key}" not found')

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        """
        Updates the PunktDict with new data.

        Args:
        - *args: Variable length argument list.
        - **kwargs: Arbitrary keyword arguments.

        Notes:
        - Converts all nested dictionaries in the new data to PunktDict objects
          if the `convert_all_dicts_recursively` option is enabled.
        """
        if dictconfig.convert_all_dicts_recursively:
            args = [self.__class__(x) for x in args]
        super().update(*args, **kwargs)

    def _check_forbidden_key(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Checks if a key is forbidden.
        Method can be overwritten

        Args:
        - *args: Variable length argument list.
        - **kwargs: Arbitrary keyword arguments.

        Returns:
        - False always.
        """
        return False

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        """
        Handles attribute access in the PunktDict.

        Args:
        - item: The attribute name.

        Returns:
        - The created nested PunktDict if `allow_nested_attribute_creation` is enabled.

        Raises:
        - AttributeError: If `allow_nested_attribute_creation` is disabled or the attribute is forbidden.
        """
        if not self._check_forbidden_key(item):
            if dictconfig.allow_nested_attribute_creation:
                self[item] = self.__class__({})
                return self[item]
        raise AttributeError
```

Use it like this:

```
import sys
from punktdict import PunktDict, dictconfig, convert_to_dict

# Configure PunktDict behavior
dictconfig.allow_nested_attribute_creation = True
dictconfig.allow_nested_key_creation = True
dictconfig.convert_all_dicts_recursively = True
PunktDict._check_forbidden_key = (
    lambda self, x: (x.startswith("_ipython") or x == "_repr_mimebundle_")
)

# Create a PunktDict object
d = PunktDict({'popeye': {'mole': {'bole': 'dolle'}}})

# Access and modify nested dictionary values
d['hallo']['baba'] = 11
d.lll.ddd.xxx = 333

# Update PunktDict with new data
d.update({'rrrx': {'xxxxx': 'bbbb'}})
d.rrrx.xxxxxxx = []
d.rrrx.xxxxxxx.append(3)

# Access nested dictionary values using attribute syntax
d['gggg']['xxxxx']['tttt'] = 12
print(d.gggg.xxxxx.tttt)

# Convert PunktDict to a regular dictionary
di = convert_to_dict(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna be a party pooper (hat tip Arnold).

YOU SHOULD NOT WANT TO DO THIS.  I'm sure you know this, but an attribute is a feature of the object (in this case the dictionary), while a key is a hash mapped to a value.

Why would you want to convert one to the other?  Why would you want code to look like its accessing object fields?

In case you are wondering what drove me here - How's this for weirdness in an api I'm looking at:

```
description = record.name + ' is cool.'
```

works, but:

```
record.name = record.firstname + record.lastname
```

does not.  It turns out the api restricts 'attribute writing' in their dynamic api (using eval to execute python code), but not attribute reading, and the object allows access to mapped values via attributes.  So:

```
record['name'] = record.fname
```

works, which is how the examples set a value in a dynamic function.  But you'll see examples such the second in the non-dynamic SDK version of the same functionality.

CRAZY.  And no documentation to that effect (obviously its own limitation separate from this issue).

Answer (score 0):

I get what you're trying to achieve. There are python modules that do the same.

You can checkout [attridict](https://pypi.org/project/attridict/), it does exactly that. With it you can access dict objects like attributes. Very helpful when switching from javascript :)