# Python string.format() complex object type

Tags: python

I'm writing a simple Python script which will take a json formatted config file, apply it to a template file (load the file as a string, then apply the string.format method), and then write the output to an output file.

The config file looks a little like this (JSON):

```
{
    "param1": "param",
    "param2": [
        "list1": "list item 1",
        "list2": "list item 2"
    ]
}
```

The template file looks a little like this (plain text):

```
Param1={param1}
List1={param2[0].list1}
List2={param2[0].list2}
```

And the python script looks a lot like this (Python):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys, json

if len(sys.argv) < 4:
    sys.exit("Invalid arguments")

config_file = open(sys.argv[1])
config_json = json.loads(config_file.read())
config_file.close()

template_file = open(sys.argv[2])
template_data = template_file.read()
template_file.close()

output_data = template_data.format(**config_json)

output_file = open(sys.argv[3], 'w')
output_file.write(output_data)
output_file.close()
```

The Python interpreter errors with the following:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'list1'
```

Can someone explain to me how to fix this problem? If possible I would like to avoid changing the Python script and favour the correct syntax for referencing the properties in the param2 array of objects, if such a syntax exists.

Comment: Have you checked the type of param2?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. I don't think it could be parsed.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026797/using-json-keys-as-python-attributes-in-nested-json) could help

Comment: Python errors usually also show a trace back with additional information that why you show. Please update your question with that, too.