# Python Classes: adding dynamic attributes to methods

Tags: python, class, attributes

Say we have a class:

```
class Foo (object):
...     def __init__(self,d):
...         self.d=d
...     def return_d(self):
...         return self.d
```

... and a dict:

```
d={'k1':1,'k2':2}
```

... and an instance:

```
inst=Foo(d)
```

Is there a way to dynamically add attributes to `return_d` so:

`inst.return_d.k1` would return 1?

Comment: Why won't `inst.return_d()['k1']` do? The `.` operator does an attribute lookup, so whatever `return_d` returns, should support attribute lookups, perhaps via the `__getattr__` hook. Note that you expect `return_d` to be an attribute, but you defined it as a method, so the example you state would not work on that account alone.

Comment: Partial dupe of [Accessing dict keys like an attribute in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4984647)

Comment: @Pieter: it would do. It is a silly example, just trying to lear more about classes and what I can and cannot do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd need to do two things: declare `return_d` as an attribute or property, and return a dict-like object that allows attribute access for dictionary keys. The following would work:

```
class AttributeDict(dict): 
    __getattr__ = dict.__getitem__

class Foo (object):
    def __init__(self,d):
        self.d=d

    @property
    def return_d(self):
        return AttributeDict(self.d)
```

Short demo:

```
>>> foo = Foo({'k1':1,'k2':2})
>>> foo.return_d.k1
1
```

The [`property` decorator](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) turns methods into attributes, and the [`__getattr__` hook](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) allows the `AttributeDict` class to look up dict keys via attribute access (the `.` operator).

Comment: Does the dict class have any important attributes that this might obscure?

Comment: `__getattr__` is only consulted for attributes not found otherwise; methods on the dict object trump keys with the same name.