# Pandas column access w/column names containing spaces

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

If I import or create a pandas column that contains no spaces, I can access it as such:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df1 = DataFrame({'key': ['b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b'],
                 'data1': range(7)})

df1.data1
```

which would return that series for me.  If, however, that column has a space in its name, it isn't accessible via that method:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df2 = DataFrame({'key': ['a','b','d'],
                 'data 2': range(3)})

df2.data 2      # <--- not the droid I'm looking for.
```

I know I can access it using .xs():

```
df2.xs('data 2', axis=1)
```

There's *got* to be another way.  I've googled it like mad and can't think of any other way to google it.  I've read all 96 entries here on SO that contain "column" and "string" and "pandas" and could find no previous answer.  Is this the only way, or is there something better?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I think *the* default way is to use the bracket method instead of the dot notation.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': ['b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b'],
    'dat a1': range(7)
})

df1['dat a1']
```

The other methods, like exposing it as an attribute are more for convenience.

Comment: Thanks, that one shouldn't have stumped me like it did.

Comment: Thank for the comment. I normally use dot to access my columns (df.col_name) but just know this trick to access the column names with space by using df[column name with space"]. Thx.

Answer (score 88):

Old post, but may be interesting: an idea (which is destructive, but does the job if you want it quick and dirty) is to rename columns using underscores:

```
df1.columns = [c.replace(' ', '_') for c in df1.columns]
```

Comment: If you want to standardize the columns to lowercase as well, use `df1.columns = [c.lower().replace(' ', '_') for c in df1.columns]`

Comment: A nice way to read and cleanup a dataframe is using method chaining. Instead of using a list comprehension to set the `columns` attribute, you can use the `rename` method: `df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'key': ['b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b'], 'dat a1': range(7)}).rename(lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_'), axis=1)`

Comment: An alternative is to use the `strip()` function: `df1.columns = [c.strip() for c in df1.columns]`

Answer (score 24):

If you like to supply spaced columns name to pandas method like assign you can dictionarize your inputs.

```
df.assign(**{'space column': (lambda x: x['space column2'])})
```

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with `df['Column Name']`

Comment: That's a straightforward one.

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted answer works for column-specification when using dictionaries or []-selection, it does not generalise to other situations where one needs to refer to columns, such as the `assign` method:

```
> df.assign("data 2" = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1)
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Comment: Yes, I would love a solution to this since there is no chainable alternative to `assign` that I know of. I guess this should be a separate SO question.

Comment: the answer is to pass a dictionary as a keyword argument. `df.assign(**{"data 2": lambda x: x.sum(axis=1)})`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to apply filtering, that's also possible with column names having spaces in it, e.g. filtering for NULL-values or empty strings:

```
df_package[(df_package['Country_Region Code'].notnull()) | 
(df_package['Country_Region Code'] != u'')]
```

as I figured out thanks to [Rutger Kassies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1755432/rutger-kassies) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13758846/7773582).

Comment: this is obvious once you discover how to refer to them?