# why does it keep saying "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:"

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract data from column, but it is keep saying there is an another exception.

any help will be appreciated

```
data = pd.read_csv('2019_data.csv')
data.head()


    Player Name Date    Statistic   Variable    Value
0   Cameron Champ   2019-08-18  Driving Distance    Driving Distance - (ROUNDS) 78
1   Rory McIlroy    2019-08-18  Driving Distance    Driving Distance - (ROUNDS) 68
2   Luke List   2019-08-18  Driving Distance    Driving Distance - (ROUNDS) 66
3   Wyndham Clark   2019-08-18  Driving Distance    Driving Distance - (ROUNDS) 87
4   Dustin Johnson  2019-08-18  Driving Distance    Driving Distance - (ROUNDS) 69


df = data.groupby(['Player Name']).first()

ds = df.sort_values(by = ["Value"])

ds["Player Name"]
```

but it says

```
KeyError: 'Player Name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Comment: Because exception in your pandas code is raised to python core and python raises another exception.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas doesn't like spaces in column names. Look this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30514678/1688590

Comment: If you think it is already answered in another question, can you please mark it as duplicate?

Comment: I had already marked it as duplicate before you commented, but being Tatsuya a new contributor it may feel rude to just "answer" with a flag.