# Access to DataFrame element by column label containing special character hyphen '-' fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

so i have a

```
df = read_excel(...)
```

loop does work:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows(): #loop through rows
    a = df[df.columns].SignalName[i] #column "SignalName" of row i, is read
    b = (row[7]) #column "Bus-Signalname" of row i, taken primitively=hardcoded
```

Access to a is ok, how to replace the hardcoded b = (row[7]) with a dynamically found/located "Bus-Signalname" element from the excel table. Which are the many ways to do this?

```
 b = df[df.columns].Bus-Signalname[i]
```

does not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757090/pandas-column-access-w-column-names-containing-spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the whole column, run: `df['Bus-Signalname']`.
So called *attribute notation* (*df.Bus-Signalname*) will **not** work here,
since "-" is not allowed as a part of an attribute name.

It is treated as *minus* operator, so:

- the expression before it is *df.Bus*, but *df* probably has no
  column with whis name, so an exception is thrown,
- what occurs after it (*Signalname*) is expected to be e.g. a variable,
  but you probably have no such variable and this is another reason
  which could cause an exception.

Note also that then you wrote `[i]`.
As I understand, `i` is an integer and you want to access element No *i* from this column.

Note that the column you retrieved is a **Series** with index just the
same as your whole *DataFrame*.

If the index is a default one (consecutive numbers, starting from *0*),
you will succeed. Otherwise (if the index does not contain value of *i*)
you will fail.

A more *pandasonic* syntax to access an element in a DataFrame is:

```
df.loc[i, 'Bus-Signalname']
```

where *i* is the index of the row in question and *Bus-Signalname* is the column name.

Answer (score 0):

@Valdi_Bo

thank you. In the loop, both

```
df.loc[i, 'Bus-Signalname']
```

and

```
df['Bus-Signalname'][i]
```

work.