# Read columns with brackets

Tags: python, pandas, syntax-error

I'm trying to read a column named `Goods_Issue_Date_(GID)`

How can I read this?

I tried:

```
Df.Goods_Issue_Date_(GID)
```

Returns Invalid Syntax

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this column besides "read"? What have you tried? Post the relevant parts of the code of what you've tried

Comment: I know the duplicate is specifically about spaces, but the same advice is true for any columns which are not valid attribute names. Either rename the columns as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30514678/15497888) or use standard __get_item__ access with square braces [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13758846/15497888)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following dataframe as an example

```
data = [['Carrots', "Tuesday"], ['Apples', "Monday"], ['Pears', "Sunday"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Product', 'Goods_Issue_Date_(GID)'])

df.head()

   Product Goods_Issue_Date_(GID)
0  Carrots                Tuesday
1   Apples                 Monday
2    Pears                 Sunday
```

You can select the `Goods_Issue_Date_(GID)` column like so

```
df['Goods_Issue_Date_(GID)']

0    Tuesday
1     Monday
2     Sunday
Name: Goods_Issue_Date_(GID), dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks you it works, hope it works same way in condition syntax