# dictionary properties in Python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing dict keys like an attribute in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984647/accessing-dict-keys-like-an-attribute-in-python)

Is there a way to implement this in python

```
foo = {'test_1': 1,'test_2': 2}
print foo.test_1
>>> 1
```

Maybe if I extend dict, but I do not know how to dynamically generate functions.

Comment: Unless you *really* *really* have to - don't... just use `foo['test_1']`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
class mydict(dict):
  def __getattr__(self, k):
    return self[k]

foo = mydict({'test_1': 1,'test_2': 2})
print foo.test_1
```

You might also want to override `__setattr__()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a similar behavior using [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). But the only drawback is, its immutable

```
>>> bar = namedtuple('test',foo.keys())(*foo.values())
>>> print bar.test_1
1
>>> print bar.test_2
2
```