# How to access items of dictionary as attributes and vice versa

Tags: python

Following is my requirement which is to be implemented in python:
I have a dictionary called context which will be updated from various parts of the program.

Now I have to create an obj called `env` which holds the dictionary context and environmental variables dictionary also.

`env` object should have all features of dictionary class along with it, it should be possible to the access the item of dictionary as attribute of the object.

For example,

> `context = {'install_path' : '/home/xyz','cwd' : '/home/xyz/Desktop'}`

the

> `context` 
>   dictionary will be updated from various parts of program.

Now I have to create `env` object which holds context dictionary and also environmental dictionary. And It should be possible to access the items of dictionary as attributes of `env` object.

For example:

```
print(env.install_path) # accessing item of context dictionary
print(env.os) #accessing environmental variable print(env)
print(env['install_path'])
print(env)
```

should produce output as:

> ```
>  /home/xyz linux 
>  /home/xyz
>  {'install_path':'/home/xyz','cwd':'/home/xyz/Desktop'}
>  all envrionmental variables
> ```

Later when the context dictionary is updated the `env` object should also be updated.

Please help how to achieve this.

Comment: It's possible, but why would you want to allow this? It just makes things more confusing - not easier...

Comment: @JonClements: That is how the requirement is

Comment: Umm, so what happens if a variable is called `update` `pop` `get` `keys` `items` etc... ?

Comment: @JonClements: All should work as expected with their common behaviour

Comment: @WesleyBaugh That's what I was thinking - was just trying to work out if there was something more to the question. But yeah - the OP should read that and see if it meets their requirement.

Comment: @WesleyBaugh: It seems to work.. But, when will print(env) work??

Comment: I just tested [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14620633/1988505) on that question, and it **correctly** handles the [problem example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9288569/1988505) shown in another answer.

Comment: I just tested with [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984647/accessing-dict-keys-like-an-attribute-in-python/9288569#9288569) But its doesn't meet my requirements

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest way to do something like that I've seen:

```
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self

if __name__ == '__main__':
    o = AttrDict(x=10)
    o.y = 20
    o['z'] = 30
    print o.x, o['y'], o.z
```

Output:

```
10 20 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of dict.

Objects have methods that get called if an attribute is missing. You can override the default implementation of these methods to do dictionary get and set operations.

```
class AttributeDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self[attr]
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        self[attr] = value
```

Previous discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984647/accessing-dict-keys-like-an-attribute-in-python)

If you need to create a new AttributeDict from an existing dictionary, you can use the following:

```
context = {'install_path' : '/home/xyz','cwd' : '/home/xyz/Desktop'}
new_dict = AttributeDict(context)
print new_dict.install_path
```

If you want a different object that just references an existing dictionary, use this

```
class ReferencedDict(object):
    def __init__(self, reference):
        self.ref = reference
    def __getattr__(self, value):
        return self.ref[value]

env = ReferencedDict(context)
print(env)
```

Comment: I tested this answer , but it doesn't cover all my requirements.. I have a dictionary which is already created and I have to create a object hold both the context dictionary and environmental dictionary.Also `print(env)` should also work

Comment: Which requirements does it specifically not cover?

Comment: `print(env)` This should display the contents of `context` dictionary along with environmental dictionary

Comment: @vinaysurve: It's not a huge conceptual leap to create an object with two `AttributeDict`s, `env` and `context`. What's the problem?

Comment: @JoelCornett: All seems to work. But when I add some items in to `context` dictionary , that is not reflected in `env` object

Comment: I did like this: `class Env(dict): __getattr = dict.__getitem__` then created object of Env like : `context = {'name' : 'vinay'} env = Env(context)` Now its possible to access `env.name` but later if i update `context` as `context['path'] = '/home/vinay'` and if I try to access `path` as `env.path` I got keyerror as `env` object is not updated. How to slove this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
class DictWithReference(dict):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._ref_other = kwargs.pop("ref", {})
        super(DictWithReference, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.__getitem__(attr)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return super(DictWithReference, self).__getitem__(attr)
        except KeyError:
            return self._ref_other[attr]
```

Usage:

```
>>> context = {'install_path' : '/home/xyz','cwd' : '/home/xyz/Desktop'}
>>> env = DictWithReference({'foo': 'bar'}, ref=context)
>>> env.foo
'bar'
>>> env['foo']
'bar'
>>> env.install_path
'/home/xyz'
>>> env['install_path']
'/home/xyz'
```