# Is there a more simple way to change and use global variables?

Tags: python, global-variables

If you declare a global variable before a function and try to change that variables in a function it throws back an error:

```
james = 100

def runthis():
    james += 5
```

This wont work.

Unless you declare the global variables again in the function, like this:

```
james = 100

def runthis():
    global james
    james += 5
```

Is there a more simple way to change the variable inside the function? It's sort of messy and annoying re-declaring variables again and again.

Comment: `global x` seems like a pretty simple way of declaring a variable as global.  How would you imagine a simpler way would look like?  That said, global variables should be a rare thing to need.  I hardly ever use the `global` keyboard.

Comment: You can reference `james` as `globals()['james']`

Comment: Sven Mrnach, well in the instance i'm needing this help for, I find myself having to change global variables in multiple function constantly its sort of a pain.

Comment: @user3579419 Well, what I'm saying is -- don't do that.  Global state is evil, and using lots of global state results in unmaintainable and untestable code.  It's a bit hard to explain this in a few comments here, but it's something every experienced programmer can confirm.

Comment: If it serves as a deterrent to using globals, so much the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying global variables is ugly in Python.  If you need to maintain state, use a [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html):

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.james = 100
    def runThis(self):
        self.james += 5
```

Or, if you need `james` to be shared among all your instances, make it a class attribute:

```
class MyClass(object):
    james = 100
    def runThis(self):
        MyClass.james += 5
```

It may not be simpler, but it is definitely more pythonic.

Comment: Genius, never really crossed my mind but its a great solution. So thanks :D

Comment: Glad you are happy with the class solution.  For others, actually, its better not to use globals.  See @martineau below.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be simpler to avoid using the global variable in the function?

```
james = 100

def runthis(value):
    return value + 5

james = runthis(james)
```

If you've got a lot of them it might make more sense to put them in a single mutable container, such as a dictionary:

```
def runthis(scores):
    scores['james'] += 5

players = {'james': 100, 'sue': 42}

runthis(players)
print players  # -> {'james': 105, 'sue': 42}
```

If you don't like the `scores['james']` notation, you could create a specialized `dict` class:

```
# from http://stackoverflow.com/a/15109345/355230
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self

def runthis(scores):
    scores.james += 5  # note use of dot + attribute name

players = AttrDict({'james': 100, 'sue': 42})

runthis(players)
print players  # -> {'james': 105, 'sue': 42}
```

Comment: Yes but in an instance where i'm working with a lot of code, that can become messy to putting so many parameters into one function.