# How to get the str from list1 to became variables based on List2 values?

Tags: python, list

I want to type `a` (from `list1`) and get `1` (from `list2`), and I don't want to use `dict{zip(a,b)}`. Is this possible? Don't want to type something like `dict['a']`, just `a`.

```
List1=['a', 'b', 'c']   
List2=[1, 24, 35]   
print(a)
```

Comment: How about `a, b, c = 1, 24, 35`?

Comment: You could use an [`AttrDict`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15109345/355230) which is `dict` subclass that would allow you to reference `my_attrdict.a` in addition to the usual `my_attrdict['a']`.

Comment: Dont dynamically create variables. If you want to map strings to other objects, use the appropriate container, in this case, a `dict`

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a function and passing the array and the string you want to fetch as a argument. Inside the function use a for-loop to match the items of the array and returning the matching item.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lists are same length and the position are always aligned, you can do

```
List1=[a, b, c]   
List2=[1, 24, 35] 
List2[List1.index(a)]
```

Comment: this will give error because a, b, c are not defined.

Comment: If the OP doesn't want to even type `dict['a']`, I don't think he'll want to type `List2[List1.index('a')]`

Comment: @L.Grozinger I assumed he just didn't want to make things into a dictionary. Sadly I can't ask for details in the comment because i don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @sqz now you can comment.

Comment: They are both from inputs, and i'll ask the OP to input an equation, so it can't be something like '100+dict['A']', it need's to be like '100+A'.