# Pymongo database object client possesses any attribute?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm going through the [PyMongo tutorial](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html)  and there's one thing that I don't understand.

We are shown that we can create a database collection like this:

```
>>>client = MongoClient()   
>>>print(client)

MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True) 

>>>db = client.test_database
>>>print(db)

Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True), 'test_database')

>>>collection = db.test_collection #posts is the collection.
>>>print(collection)

Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True), 'test_database'), 'test_collection')
```

My initial thought was: "Did they make sure to include a `test_database` attribute for the client and a `test_collection` attribute for the database just to make it work with the tutorial?" But further experimentation showed me that I could create databases and collections in this way with any "attribute name" I please! For example:

```
>>>client = MongoClient()
>>>db = client.foo
>>>print(db)

Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True), 'foo')

>>>collection = db.bar
>>>print(collection)

Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True), 'foo'), 'bar')
```

How does this work in Python? I've tried to understand it by reading the pymongo files in the GitHub repository but it's quite difficult for a newbie to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoClient overrides a "magic" method, `__getattr__`. Whenever you access an attribute on a MongoClient object that isn't actually a property or attribute of the object, for example when you access "test_database", the Python interpreter calls:

```
client.__getattr__("test_database")
```

[The implementation of `MongoClient.__getattr__`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/3.5.1/pymongo/mongo_client.py#L1018) then creates a Database object and returns it.

Database also overrides `__getattr__` to return a Collection with any name.

Both classes also override `__getitem__` so that bracketed access works:

```
client["test_database"]
```

[See the `__getattr__` docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__).

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `__getattr__` method in your class to make it work.
Simply speaking - whenever you access an attribute that is not defined in the class, `__getattr__` method will be invoked (it's actually a little more complicated). See example below:

```
class Database(object):

    def __init__(self, host):
        self.host = host

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return Collection(name)

class Collection(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Collection name={0}>'.format(self.name)

>>> db = Database('www.example.com')
>>> db.host
'example.com'
>>> db.foo
<Collection name=foo>
>>> db.bar
<Collection name=bar>
```

You can read more about `__getattr__` here:
[Python: how to implement __getattr__()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237659/python-how-to-implement-getattr)