# Generalized __eq__() method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to create a generalized `__eq__()` method for the following Class.  Basically I'd like to be able to add another property (`nick`) without having to change `__eq__()`

I imagine I can do this somehow by iterating over `dir()` but I wonder if there is a way to create a comprehension that just delivers the properties.

```
 class Person:
     def __init__(self, first, last):
         self.first=first
         self.last=last

     @property
     def first(self):
         assert(self._first != None)
         return self._first
     @first.setter
     def first(self,fn):
         assert(isinstance(fn,str))
         self._first=fn

     @property
     def last(self):
         assert(self._last != None)
         return self._last
     @last.setter
     def last(self,ln):
         assert(isinstance(ln,str))
         self._last=ln
     @property
     def full(self):
         return f'{self.first} {self.last}'

     def __eq__(self, other):
         return self.first==other.first and self.last==other.last

 p = Person('Raymond', 'Salemi')
 p2= Person('Ray', 'Salemi')
```

Comment: Store the data in a dictionary. Then you can check for equivalence of the two dictionaries. Instead of using properties consider overwriting `__getattr__` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237659/python-how-to-implement-getattr)

Comment: Did you notice you defined `first.setter` twice?

Comment: Thanks. That's what I get for cut-and-paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the properties of a `Class` with a construct like this:

```
from itertools import chain
@classmethod
def _properties(cls):
    type_dict = dict(chain.from_iterable(typ.__dict__.items() for typ in reversed(cls.mro())))
    return {k for k, v in type_dict.items() if 'property' in str(v)}
```

The `__eq__` would become something like this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    properties = self._properties() & other._properties()
    if other._properties() > properties and self._properties() > properties:
        # types are not comparable
        return False
    try:
        return all(getattr(self, prop) == getattr(other, prop) for prop in properties)
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

The reason to work with the `reversed(cls.mro())` is so something like this also works:

```
class Worker(Person):
    @property
    def wage(self):
        return 0

p4 = Worker('Raymond', 'Salemi')

print(p4 == p3)
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: That nails it! Thank you!

Comment: This is complete overkill. What advantages does this unreadable monstrosity have over `vars(self) == vars(other)`?

Comment: How does vars(self) == vars(others) handle properties that create a value using some algorithm?

Comment: @RaySalemi It ignores them. But that doesn't matter, because properties (usually) calculate their results based on other instance attributes, so as long as all instance attributes are equal, the property values will also be equal. Of course, if you have a weird property that returns `random()` or something similar, then that could be a problem.

Comment: @Aran-Fey that monstrosity is what I came up with to also work with inherited properties. If you think your solution is better, then feel free to post it as an answer

Answer (score 8):

You could use `__dict__` to check if everything is the same, which scales for all attributes:

If the objects are not matching types, I simply return `False`.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first, last, nick):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.nick = nick

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__  if type(self) == type(other) else False

>>> p = Person('Ray', 'Salemi', 'Ray')
>>> p2= Person('Ray', 'Salemi', 'Ray')
>>> p3 = Person('Jared', 'Salemi', 'Jarbear')

>>> p == p2
True
>>> p3 == p2
False
>>> p == 1
False
```

Comment: This might be a way to go, but it won't handle derived properties.  For example, I might want to say 

    `return self.full == other.full` 

And use a list of derived properties.

Comment: @RaySalemi How so? Shouldn't derived properties, pretty much by definition, be equal if all the other properties (that they could possibly be derived from) are equal?

Comment: @RaySalemi Unless you have some randomness with how you generate derived properties this should still work.

Comment: Yes. But you see the broader point about comparing actual properties.

Comment: @RaySalemi you could also try `return dir(self) == dir(other) && self.__dict__ == other.__dict__`, although it seems redundant.

Answer (score -1):

you can try to do this, it will also work if you want eq inside dict and set

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    """Overrides the default implementation"""
    if isinstance(self, other.__class__):
        return self.__hash__() == other.__hash__()

    return NotImplemented

def __hash__(self):
    """Overrides the default implementation,
       and set which fieds to use for hash generation
    """
    __make_hash = [
         self.first
    ]
    return hash(tuple(sorted(list(filter(None, __make_hash)))))
```

Comment: Never ever ever ever ever compare objects based on their hash values.

Comment: Also, why are you filtering and sorting that `__make_hash` list? Seems completely unnecessary to me.

Comment: i use __slots__ =  [] and just copy past part of code