# Any similar to namedtuple for list?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a set of keywords which contain a default value. Say:

```
a_dict =\
{'key1': 'value1'
'key2': 'value2'
... and so on ...}
```

I don't want to use a `dict` because I find it annoying having to type:

```
a_dict['key2']
```

in order to get the keyword's value. I would like to have all of these
keywords available on a variable (say `var`) so that when I press 'Tab Key' after
$var.$ I get all posible keywords. I have tried with $namedtuple$ from
$collections$ module but I run in the problem where I can't modify none of
the values of each key (because it is a touple). The good thing of
`namedtuple` is that I could iterate over it, for example:

```
for key in var:
    #do something with key
```

What I did is to create a class named `Keys` as shown next:

```
class Keys(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.key1 = 'value1'
        self.key2 = 'value2'
        ... and so on...
```

Now when I do:

```
keys = Keys()
```

I have all the namespace available in `keys.` and can modify all values of each
key. The problem is that now I cannot iterate over each key. And I don't know
how to set `__getitem__` method in order to iterate over the instance `keys`.

The perfect solution would be to use a `namedlist` function (similar to
`namedtuple`) but I don't know any similar function. Is there one?

How can I do it? Any other alternative will be wellcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return getattr(self, key) 
        except:
            raise AttributeError('%s is not a valid property'%key)
```

Comment: I think maybe this is the inverse of the question, which is to access dict items using attribute notation.

Comment: Ahh, maybe this is what you need? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984647/accessing-dict-keys-like-an-attribute-in-python

Comment: Ha I just found that too :P

Comment: My apologies for this duplicate. I work at home with no internet connection so I prepared the question at home. I had very little time to post the question and could not investigate the problem. Can I erase the question?