# How to make grep using Python

Tags: python, sed, grep

Pls help me.
I have some API command result:

```
[{u'task': {u'url': u'http://192.168.1.1/job/f1111111111/', u'color': u'aborted', u'name': u'f1111111111'}, u'stuck': False, u'url': u'queue/item/37/', u'inQueueSince': 1397554800875L, u'actions': [{u'causes': [{u'userName': u'admin', u'userId': u'admin', u'shortDescription': u'Started by user admin'}]}], u'why': u'Waiting for next available executor on NODE_1', u'buildable': True, u'params': u'', u'buildableStartMilliseconds': 1397554800878L, u'id': 37, u'pending': False, u'blocked': False}, {u'task': {u'url': u'http://192.168.1.1/job/1234/', u'color': u'aborted', u'name': u'1234'}, u'stuck': False, u'url': u'queue/item/36/', u'inQueueSince': 1397554797741L, u'actions': [{u'causes': [{u'userName': u'admin', u'userId': u'admin', u'shortDescription': u'Started by user admin'}]}], u'why': u'Waiting for next available executor on NODE_1', u'buildable': True, u'params': u'', u'buildableStartMilliseconds': 1397554797744L, u'id': 36, u'pending': False, u'blocked': False}]
```

How can I make grep using PYthon to have the next output:

u'name': u'f1111111111'

u'name': u'1234

Comment: Do you mean searching strings in python with regular expressions (aka import re), or calling something on the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better loop through your string like this:

```
>>> s=[{u'task': {u'url': u'http://192.168.1.1/job/f1111111111/', u'color': u'aborted', u'name': u'f1111111111'}, u'stuck': False, u'url': u'queue/item/37/', u'inQueueSince': 1397554800875L, u'actions': [{u'causes': [{u'userName': u'admin', u'userId': u'admin', u'shortDescription': u'Started by user admin'}]}], u'why': u'Waiting for next available executor on NODE_1', u'buildable': True, u'params': u'', u'buildableStartMilliseconds': 1397554800878L, u'id': 37, u'pending': False, u'blocked': False}, {u'task': {u'url': u'http://192.168.1.1/job/1234/', u'color': u'aborted', u'name': u'1234'}, u'stuck': False, u'url': u'queue/item/36/', u'inQueueSince': 1397554797741L, u'actions': [{u'causes': [{u'userName': u'admin', u'userId': u'admin', u'shortDescription': u'Started by user admin'}]}], u'why': u'Waiting for next available executor on NODE_1', u'buildable': True, u'params': u'', u'buildableStartMilliseconds': 1397554797744L, u'id': 36, u'pending': False, u'blocked': False}]
>>> for i in s:
...     print i['task']['name']
... 
f1111111111
1234
```

You can store the information in a list:

```
>>> l=[]
>>> for i in s:
...     l.append(i['task']['name'])
... 
>>> 
>>> print l
[u'f1111111111', u'1234']
```

Answer (score 3):

Normaly you use `grep` (or regular expression) only as last resort to get structure out of a string literal. In your case you already got a kind of structured result, thus you should be able to iterate over it. (= much faster parsing)

```
  for row in result:  #iterate over the result list
    # do something with the row
    print row["task"]["name"] #access particular key
```

The ideal would be to convert the result into a custom dictionary alike structure, where you can access the result properties directly e.g.  `row.task.name`. How to get there is nicely explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984647/accessing-dict-keys-like-an-attribute-in-python)

Comment: Ups. @fedorqui was faster ;-)

Comment: Good one, I had already answered almost the same but your answer gives more detail so I find it very useful. +1