# What is the difference between attributes and fields?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to understand the difference between these two syntaxes:

Ex:.

```
obj = { 
'atrib1': 1,
'atrib2': 2
}

#accessing atrib1
print(obj['atrib1'])

#why can't I access like this, and what is accessible in this way?
#print(obj.atrib1)
```

Comment: These two syntaxes are nothing alike. I'm not sure why you would have an expectation that they would produce the same results (besides the fact that in Lua or maybe JavaScript, they would).

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. This question is a possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984647/accessing-dict-keys-like-an-attribute)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing dict keys like an attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984647/accessing-dict-keys-like-an-attribute)

Comment: @khelwood: "How to do it" is not the same question as "why you can't do it".

Comment: There's information in the other questions' answers about why they are different operations.

Comment: And what makes you think either of these syntaxes involves anything called "fields"?

Answer (score 2):

In languages like Lua and JavaScript, where what you can access via `obj.attr` and `obj["attr"]` is the same, you'll notice that the APIs for manipulating a dictionary are not actually part of the dictionary *object*. For example, if you want to get the keys of a dictionary as a list, in JavaScript, you call `Objects.keys()`, passing the dictionary as a parameter. You don't call `the_dictionary.keys()`.

The reason these are external functions rather than member functions is that the keys in the key/value dictionary could override member functions. If a dictionary just so happened to have a key named "keys", any member function named "keys" would be overridden. Therefore, functions which act on dictionaries cannot be members of the actual dictionary type.

In Python, they can be. The contents of a dictionary are accessed via `[]`, but the member functions, the operations which act upon those contents, are accessed via `.name` notation. That's the distinction between attributes and "fields". And that means the operations on dictionaries are actually *on the dictionary*.

You can of course [make them one and the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14620633/734069), but then you recreate the original problem. And since Python doesn't have that problem normally, it doesn't have non-member functions you can easily call to do that job. You can still do it via the class object, but it's clearly non-Pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, objects have attributes, which may be accessed with the `.name` syntax.  But some object classes implement a `__getitem__` method, which is accessed with the `['name']` syntax.  Most notably, the `dict` class:

```
In [102]: obj = {  
     ...: 'atrib1': 1, 
     ...: 'atrib2': 2 
     ...: } 
     ...:                                                                                            
In [103]: type(obj)                                                                                  
Out[103]: dict
```

`obj['atrib1']` is translated by the interpreter into a method call:

```
In [104]: obj.__getitem__('atrib1')                                                                   
Out[104]: 1
```

`obj.atrib1` is translated into an `__getattribute__` call:

```
In [105]: obj.__getattribute__('atrib1')                                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-ec1bc68ae22d> in <module>
----> 1 obj.__getattribute__('atrib1')

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'atrib1'
```

That class does have attributes like `__getattribute__` and `keys`, which are functions:

```
In [106]: obj.__getattribute__('__getitem__')                                                        
Out[106]: <function dict.__getitem__>
In [107]: obj.__getattribute__('keys')                                                               
Out[107]: <function dict.keys>
```

So the `dict` object does have a lot of attributes, but the items access with keys aren't attributes.

Some classes also implement a `__dict__` attribute, which stores user defined attributes.  `vars(obj)` returns that as dict.  But for this `dict` class:

```
In [108]: vars(obj)                                                                                  
...
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute
```

Here's a little class that has both:

```
In [111]: class mydict(dict): 
     ...:     pass 
     ...:                                                                                            
In [112]: obj1 = mydict()                                                                            
In [113]: obj1 = mydict(atrib1=1, atrib2=2)                                                          
In [114]: obj1                                                                                       
Out[114]: {'atrib1': 1, 'atrib2': 2}
In [115]: obj1.__dict__                                                                              
Out[115]: {}
In [116]: obj1.foobar = 42                                                                           
In [117]: vars(obj1)                                                                                 
Out[117]: {'foobar': 42}
In [118]: obj1.foobar                                                                                
Out[118]: 42
In [119]: obj1['atrib1']                                                                             
Out[119]: 1
```