# Grab values from JSON objects in Python and assign them to a variable

Tags: python, json

I would like to grab some values within a JSON object using Python and assign them to variables for further use in the html frontend.

I tried it using the w3c resource and by googling but I can't get any successful print:

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get("https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/teams/team/33")
team_data = response.json()

team_name = team_data.teams.name

print(team_name)
```

This is the JSON Object i get from the external API:

```
{
    "api": {
        "results": 1,
        "teams": [
            {
                "team_id": 33,
                "name": "Manchester United",
                "code": "MUN",
                "logo": "https://media.api-football.com/teams/33.png",
                "country": "England",
                "founded": 1878,
                "venue_name": "Old Trafford",
                "venue_surface": "grass",
                "venue_address": "Sir Matt Busby Way",
                "venue_city": "Manchester",
                "venue_capacity": 76212
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The debug console tells me `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'teams'`

Comment: You can't access dict keys like a JS object using dot notation. Use key lookups: `team_data['teams']` or the safer `get` : `team_data.get('teams')`

Comment: @JacobIRR `team_data.teams.name` in this case would not have worked even in JS becuase `team_data['teams']` is a list

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984647/accessing-dict-keys-like-an-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONs (JavaScript Object Notation) are overall JavaScript objects used for storing serialized data. The python interpreter has an specific module `import json`that allows to charge JSON files to Python dicts in the RAM of your machine.

In your situation:

```
with open('team_data.json', "r") as fobj:
    dataset = json.load(fobj)
    print('Teams data: ', dataset['api']['teams'])
```

From here you can work with it as a normal dict.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I get the JSON from an external API. Thus using your code gives me ```no such file 'team_data.json', how to avoid this?

Comment: So you are not storing the json, and there is no json file created yet, sorry I miss interepreted. Try directly `print(team_data['api']['teams'])`