# Accessing dict "values" like an attribute?

Tags: python, dictionary, properties, attributes

What I am looking for is having something like this:

```
self.info['key'].attr2
```

But I'm not sure what would be the most elegant way to achieve it. So far I have defined a dictionary like below but don't have attributes from it.

```
self.info  = {}
self.info.update({'key':
                        {'attr1':   2,
                         'attr2':   lambda: self.func(arg1)}
                       })
```

But then I would have to use it like:

```
self.info['key']['attr2']()
```

Note that what I am looking for is accessing the dictionary values like attributes. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984647/accessing-dict-keys-like-an-attribute) has an answer which can be used in my case also probably that is I make an object out of the sub-dictionary from above and give it as a value to the main dictionary.

But I wonder if there is nicer way, perhaps with decorators and with less lines of codes and maybe even without using dictionaries do to something like what I described in the first line, perhaps even better like:

```
self['key'].attr2
```

Comment: `collections.namedtuple`, as suggested in the thread you link?

Comment: or something like this --> https://github.com/Infinidat/munch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing dict keys like an attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984647/accessing-dict-keys-like-an-attribute)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: there's also an AttrDict object.  see https://github.com/bcj/AttrDict  not sure what the author means with the read-only status though, might be time to look for alternative packages.  one advantage is that you can still use dictionary methods, i.e, `o.attr2` or `o.get("attr2")`.  mostly, the SimpleNamespace answer would be my pick.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a short wrapper to access dict keys as attributes:

```
class nameddict(dict):
   __getattr__ = dict.__getitem__

info = nameddict()
info['key'] = nameddict(attr1=2, attr2=3)
```

Then `info['key'].attr2` as well as `info['key']['attr2']` and `info.key.attr2` returns `3`.

Answer (score 4):

if you want a more dynamic container for which you don't need to declare the attributes like in namedtuple you can use SimpleNamespace object.

```
from types import SimpleNamespace as ns
info  = {}
info.update({'key': ns(attr1=2, attr2=lambda x: x+1)})
```

Comment: This is only Python 3.

Comment: @Lior what if the names 'attr1' and 'attr2' were given to me as strings in the begining.

Comment: Is it really a safe way to use SimpleNameSpace en masse?

Comment: @Friedrich--СлаваУкраїні this is 2020 (and now 2023) ... of course it's python 3, get with the times!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields), as suggested in the thread you link:

```
Attrs = namedtuple("Attrs", ["attr1", "attr2"])
info = {"key": Attrs(attr1=2, attr2=lambda: 4)}
info["key"].attr2()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a library for that called Box. Very convenient. 
https://pypi.org/project/python-box/

It handles all kinds of edge cases, like dictionaries inside dictionaries and lists etc.

`pip install python-box`

```py
from box import Box

movie_box = Box({
    "Robin Hood: Men in Tights": {
        "imdb_stars": 6.7,
        "length": 104,
        "stars": [ {"name": "Cary Elwes", "imdb": "nm0000144", "role": "Robin Hood"},
                   {"name": "Richard Lewis", "imdb": "nm0507659", "role": "Prince John"} ]
    }
})

movie_box.Robin_Hood_Men_in_Tights.imdb_stars
# 6.7

movie_box.Robin_Hood_Men_in_Tights.stars[0].name
# 'Cary Elwes'
```