# How to have half dataclass half dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, python-dataclasses

There is quite a big, extensive API that works with JSON I am interfacing with.

I also have some code that already uses `response["Value"]` quite extensively.

I can create my own wrapper with @propreties to access specific data and inherit from dictionary to support both .Value and ["Value"] accesses:

```
class ApiValue(dict):
   @property
   def Value(self):
       return self["Value"]
```

However, this is a lot to type, I would want to just write `Value: str`.

But, when using `@dataclass`, I would have to list *all* JSON keys, which is not possible as the JSON change with version and I do not want to maintain it and I do not use all fields. I could use `dacite` and ignore other keys in a @dataclass, but then I can't inherit from `dict`, `__getitem__` will not work for fields not listed, and I have to port *all* the code at once.

Is there a solution I could use or write that would access with `__getitem__` any field in a dictionary, but then have `fields: type` fields listed and auto-created from the dictionary? I have not found a good solution.

The fields are used for read-only access, so I do not have to care about redundancy or assignment (but, it would be super nice to have).

I try the following:

```
class FieldDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return getattr(self, name) if hasattr(self, name) else super()[name]


class Response(FieldDict):
    Value: str

rr = Response({"Value": 123, "Value2": 234})
assert rr.Value == 123
assert rr["Value"] == rr.Value
assert rr["Value2"] == 234
```

But `Reponse` has no field `Value`.

Comment: With your last example you're trying to turn `rr["Value"]` (`rr.__getitem__("Value")`) into `rr.Value`, which is exactly backwards. You want to intercept attribute access and proxy it to indexing. Maybe look at an existing attrdict implementation - https://stackoverflow.com/q/4984647/3001761.

Comment: so after passing an input dict to `Response` you want a key like `"Value"` to override an instance static property/field value `rr.Value` ? And having an empty dict you want to be able to set `Value` key OR static field with `rr["Value"] = 123` ?

Comment: what is the `Value: str` line supposed to accomplish in what you tried? that's something that only makes sense in a @dataclass which this isn't

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you need there.
One thing that I am sure: inheriting from dictionaries is not a good thing - a lot of code that relies on strict dictionaries, can, with no warning, access data through Python's dictionary API, and that will totally ignore any methods you may have overiden in Python.

The stdlib offers `collections.UserDict` for people needing a custom map which will behave as a dictionary.

And now, for being able to retrieve values that are stored at a key:value pair using the dot notation (`.`), one just have to implement the `__getattr__` map.

I am not sure if that is all you need, but maybe it is:

```
from collections import UserDict

class MyMap(UserDict):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(key)
```

You can create a "dataclassesque" decorator that will add this `__getattr__` to your classes, and could introspect any annotations to create special behaviors for certain fields if you need it.

Also, anytime you need the raw dictionary (for example, for JSON encoding the whole thing again), you can simply have it at the `.data` attribute of an instance of UserDict.

Answer (score 1):

For this use case, my tiny helper library [`dotwiz`](https://dotwiz.readthedocs.io/) might shine. It essentially enables *dot*- or attribute- access for plain `dict`s in Python. Based on the benchmarks below, it does it pretty quick too.

Additionally, [`DotWizPlus`](https://dotwiz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#dotwizplus) can be used to enable attribute-access for those "pesky" keys with special characters, such as `123` or `Hello World` - since Python likes everything lower-cased and separated only by underscores `_`.

Here's a quick demo, and a side-by-side comparison with `UserDict` from the standard library:

> Disclaimer: I am the creator of the `dotwiz` library.

```py
from collections import UserDict
from timeit import timeit

# pip install dotwiz
from dotwiz import DotWiz, DotWizPlus


class MyMap(UserDict):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(key)


data = {'key1': 'v1', '2': 'v2', '123 helloWorld': 'v3'}

dw = DotWiz(data)
dwp = DotWizPlus(data)
mm = MyMap(data)

print(dw)
print(dwp)
print(mm)

assert dw.key1 == dwp.key1 == mm.key1 == 'v1'
assert dw['2'] == dwp._2 == mm['2'] == 'v2'

assert dw['123 helloWorld'] \
       == dwp._123_hello_world \
       == mm['123 helloWorld'] \
       == 'v3'

# errors (AttributeError)
# mm._2
# mm._123_hello_world

n = 100_000

print()
print('=== DotWiz ===')
print('Create:   ', round(timeit('DotWiz(data)', globals=globals(), number=n), 3))
print('GetAttr:  ', round(timeit('dw.key1', globals=globals(), number=n), 3))
print('GetItem:  ', round(timeit('dw["2"]', globals=globals(), number=n), 3))
print()
print('=== DotWizPlus ===')
print('Create:   ', round(timeit('DotWizPlus(data)', globals=globals(), number=n), 3))
print('GetAttr:  ', round(timeit('dwp.key1', globals=globals(), number=n), 3))
print('GetItem:  ', round(timeit('dwp._2', globals=globals(), number=n), 3))

print()
print('=== UserDict ===')
print('Create:   ', round(timeit('MyMap(data)', globals=globals(), number=n), 3))
print('GetAttr:  ', round(timeit('mm.key1', globals=globals(), number=n), 3))
print('GetItem:  ', round(timeit('mm["2"]', globals=globals(), number=n), 3))
```

Results on my Mac M1 laptop:

```
✫(key1='v1', 2='v2', 123 helloWorld='v3')
✪(key1='v1', _2='v2', _123_hello_world='v3')
{'key1': 'v1', '2': 'v2', '123 helloWorld': 'v3'}

=== DotWiz ===
Create:    0.045
GetAttr:   0.001
GetItem:   0.005

=== DotWizPlus ===
Create:    0.083
GetAttr:   0.001
GetItem:   0.002

=== UserDict ===
Create:    0.054
GetAttr:   0.029
GetItem:   0.008
```

As you can see, creation times for `DotWiz` are slightly improved, and `__getattr__` or dot-access times are insanely fast, since it is essentially the same as `__getattr__` as implemented in `object`, which uses underlying `object.__dict__`.

`DotWizPlus` has slightly slower creation times than `UserDict`, but the access times remain blazing fast. So using this one is a trade-off depending on whether you have such a use case, i.e. keys that have special characters in them.

### Add Custom Functions

If you'd like to type-hint attributes or set up IDE suggestion of key names, or alternatively define custom class functions and methods, the easiest approach would be to subclass from `DotWiz` or `DotWizPlus` and then use the new class or type as normal.

Example below:

```py
from dotwiz import DotWiz


class MyDotClass(DotWiz):

    # optional: added for type hinting purposes
    my_str: str
    something_else: int

    def double(self):
        return self.something_else * 2


c = MyDotClass({
    'my_str': 'test',
    'something_else': 123,
})

print(c)
print(c.something_else)
print(c.double())
```

Prints:

```
✫(my_str='test', something_else=123)
123
246
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible to cast `dotwiz` to a custom dataclass-ish type to add custom class functions and IDE completion? My keys will all be normal strings, no worry about it.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, it's totally possible. To do this, you would need to subclass from `DotWiz` or `DotWizPlus`. I'll see if I can update my answer with an example of this.