# Are there any 'gotchas' with this Python pattern?

Tags: python, coding-style

Here's the pattern I'm thinking of using:

```
class Dicty(dict): 
    def __init__(self): 
         self.__dict__ = self 

d = Dicty()
d.foo = 'bar' 
print d['foo']
>>> bar 
d['foo'] = 'baz'
print d.foo
>>> 'baz'
```

Generally, I prefer the semantics of object attribute access over dict get/set access, but there are some circumstances where dict-like access is required (for example, `d['foo-bar'] = 'baz'`) and I'd prefer not to have special getter setter methods for these cases, so thus, the dual behavior of dict & object at the same time with shared attributes.

Are there any gotchas with the above pattern?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031219/python-recursively-access-dict-via-attributes-as-well-as-index-access

Comment: `isinstance(dict, object)`. You don't need to inherit from `object`. And the implementation is more than hacky. Also: possible duplicate of [Accessing dict keys like an attribute in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984647/accessing-dict-keys-like-an-attribute-in-python)

Comment: Objects created in this manner can be pickled without problem but objects created in the style suggested by the accepted answer cannot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a less "hacky" way to achieve the same effect:

```
class Dicty(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self[key]

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value
```

I *think* that your way may work fine as well, but setting the `__dict__` attribute like that seems a bit iffy style-wise, and is bound to raise some questions if anyone else ends up reading your code.

Comment: You should catch and translate `KeyError` — `__getattr__` is supposed to throw `AttributeError`.

Comment: If you're going to do that, it's better to just do `__getattr__ = __getitem__` and `__setattr__ = __setitem__`. Simpler, and one less function call.

Comment: @kindall @PiotrLegnica: You both make excellent (although mutually exclusive) points! Thanks! :)

Comment: @kindall, that's an awesome idea!

Comment: @GearoidMurphy. I am interested in pickling data containers that support the `container.attribute` syntax . Is there a reason why these objects cannot be pickled? Do you have any suggestions for an alternative solution that supports pickling?

Comment: Use the approach that 'slacy' describes in his question, it works fine

Comment: doesnt  seem to work for nested object. And what if the key in the dict has spaces..

Answer (score 3):

Don't set `self.__dict__`. Call `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` on the superclass. Also, `dict` inherits from `object` so you don't need to specify it.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things. One is if you try and use a dictionary method, such as `keys`, you won't be able to get it now. There were some other issues I ran into, such as being pickle-able and copy-able.

But I have implemented something that does this without those problems. You can see it here, it's the AttrDict class in the [dictlib.py module](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/aid/pycopia/dictlib.py). That module also contains a class that can wrap another mapping style object, in cases where it can't be subclassed.