# Python Key Error can't parse fields

Tags: python

I'm writing a script and iterating over a list to turn it into a JSON. My code:

`Mbody` is the name of the list I'm pulling info from.

```
index = 38
payload = {}

i = 0
while i < Number_SKUs: 
    SKU_size = 2
    size_index = 4
    value_index = 1
    time_index = 4
    ms_index = 2

    payload[i].sku = Mbody[index:(index + SKU_size*2)]
    index = index + SKU_size*2
    print(payload[i].sku)
    i+=1
```

For some reason, this is resulting in

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "parser.py", line 101, in <module> payload[i].sku = Mbody[index:(index + SKU_size*2)]
> KeyError: 0
> ```

I have searched on stack exchange and found several similar questions, but none of which answer mine. What's the best way to iterate over a list and parse the skus? This will become a JSON eventually, but I could work with it in an array for the time being and use a dict to put it into a JSON later.

Comment: `payload` is empty, so what is `payload[i]` supposed to be?

Comment: Maybe something like `payload[i] = {sku: Mbody[index:(index + SKU_size*2)]}`. But then where is `payload[i].tag` supposed to come from?

Comment: payload[i] would become something like payload1.sku = [1011a]. Payload1 should become whatever value is held in the Mbody[index:(index + sku_size*2)]. Mbody is a log character string. So this would end up reading something like (payloadd1.sku = [38:(38+4)])

Comment: What about `.tag`, where does that come from?

Comment: edited - that should have said something else.

Comment: Have you tried using [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but this will become a json by the time the script finishes. If you have info to help that along I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python you have to name the keys of a dictionary to interact with them.

```
p['a']['b']
# This is element b of p['a']

p['a'].b
# This is function b in object p['a']
```

Dotted notation is not available by default although some people have [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279212/how-to-use-dot-notation-for-dict-in-python) to [add that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352181/how-to-use-a-dot-to-access-members-of-dictionary).

Ignoring those, we can make some changes to your code to start working with the usual notation.

```
index = 38
# This can just be a list, because i is continuous between 0 and Number_SKUs
payload = []

i = 0
while i < Number_SKUs:
    SKU_size = 2
    size_index = 4
    value_index = 1
    time_index = 4
    ms_index = 2

    # Each item is going to be a new dictionary, which we will
    # eventually add the the list of payloads
    new_payload = {}

    # Now we can create a dict entry for key 'sku' in new_payload
    new_payload['sku'] = Mbody[index:(index + SKU_size * 2)]

    # We can't do this, because tag_size is undefined
    #
    # index = index + tag_size * 2

    # We can't do this, because we have not yet added a 'tag' key 
    # to payload.
    #
    # print(payload[i]['tag'])

    # Now append new_payload to payload
    payload.append(new_payload)
    i += 1
```