# how can I access attributes that have the same name as reserved keywords?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword

I am calling an API that is returning an `AttributeDict` that has a number of attributes, such as `to` and `from`.

To access these attributes, I am using dot notation. For example, I use `object.to` and that works fine.

When I try to use `object.from`, I get an error that says `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. I assume this is because [`from` is a keyword in Python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/keyword-list).

If this is the case, is it possible to access `from` with a dot? For now, I am using `object["from"]`, which is working, but does not match the rest of my code.

Comment: And this is why `AttributeDict` is usually [a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279212/how-to-use-dot-notation-for-dict-in-python/16279578#comment23318936_16279450). They're smearing the lines between "data" and "code".

Comment: Instance and class attributes are subject to the same naming conventions as variables.  In a sense, variables are attributes of the module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's possible to use `getattr` to access such attributes:

```
val = getattr(ad, 'from')
```

this is more cumbersome than the `ad['from']` syntax your AttributeDict supports, and does not satisfy your desire for dotted notation.

There is currently no option to access such attributes with dotted notation. Just stick with indexing. It handles reserved names, names with spaces/hyphens/etc. in them, and names that collide with existing methods (assuming a reasonable AttributeDict implementation). Even if you used `getattr`, `getattr(ad, 'get')` would still probably return the AttributeDict's `get` method instead of the value for a `'get'` key.

Comment: Is it typically recommended to use indexing everywhere in the program?

Comment: @python_crypto_questions it's not recommended to give attributes the same name as keywords in the first place. It's recommended to just use the `obj.attribute` syntax.