# Python Class property behave as Dictionary

Tags: python

I have a very simple class that defines properties like:

```
class Person:
    fields = set()

    @property
    def id(self):
        self.fields.add('id')
        return 'person.id'
```

The idea is for this class to record which properties have been accessed. Now the problem comes when I need to start supporting: `person.metadata.key` where metadata is basically an HStore object or 1 level JSON, the key is arbitrary and the idea is for the class Person so record access to any of the keys in `metadata`. I tried something like this:

```
class CustomerBulkContext:

    fields = set()

    class PersonMetadata:
        def __getitem__(self, attr):
            fields.add(f'metadata.{attr}')
            return f'person.metadata.{attr}'

    metadata = CustomerMetadataContext()
```

Now obviously the problem is that `fields` inside PersonMetadata is not a known variable at this point. How can I overcome this issue, I don't know if it's possible to do in Python without too much code.

Comment: Might be looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16279578/9848926

Comment: There is no clean way to do this. You'd have to have the object returned by `.metadata` communicate that

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is right. To expand on his answer, you will need to count data access in the class that actually contains the data being accessed. This is because the `get` dunder methods (`__getattribute__`, `__getitem__`, etc.) only receive a ref of the item inside themselves. i.e. `object.object1.object2` will have `object` receiving `object1`, and `object1` receiving `object2`. In other words, `object` never sees `object2` access. Unless you want to do some funky run-time code inspection, or larger wrapper class, which both are more messy, this implementation won't be "super" clean.

Comment: dont you think use of  `logger` would be better option ?

Comment: What do you mean by "behave as dictionary" in the title of this question, btw?

Answer (score 0):

In order to track accesses like `person.metadata.key` you'd have to have `person.metadata` return an object which itself tracks how it was accessed. In order to track the whole chain, you'd pass the chain so far to the object.

Something like:

```py
class AccessTracker:
    def __init__(self, path=()):
        self._path = path

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print('Accessed %s in %s' % (name, self._path))
        return AccessTracker(self._path + (name,))
```