# Adding properties dynamically to a Python class that point to items in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to attach properties dynamically to a class (`Registry`) for the sake of easy access to values in a dict. I am using `defaultdict` to define the dictionary, with the default value as an empty `list`.

But because of the way I am accessing the list values in the dictionary while defining the property, I end up with all properties pointing to the same list object.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/subhashb/adb75a3a05a611c3d9193da695d46dd4

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from enum import Enum


class ElementTypes(Enum):
    PHONE = "PHONE"
    CAR = "CAR"


class Registry:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.setup_properties()
        instance = super(Registry, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return instance

    def __init__(self):
        self._elements = {}

    def register(self, element_type, item):
        if element_type.value not in self._elements:
            self._elements[element_type.value] = []

        self._elements[element_type.value].append(item)

    def get(self, element_type):
        return self._elements[element_type.value]

    @classmethod
    def setup_properties(cls):
        for item in ElementTypes:
            prop_name = item.value
            prop = property(lambda self: getattr(self, "get")(item))

            setattr(Registry, prop_name.lower(), prop)


registry = Registry()
registry.register(ElementTypes.PHONE, "phone1")
registry.register(ElementTypes.PHONE, "phone2")
registry.register(ElementTypes.CAR, "car1")
registry.register(ElementTypes.CAR, "car2")

assert dict(registry._elements) == {
    "CAR": ["car1", "car2"],
    "PHONE": ["phone1", "phone2"],
}
assert hasattr(registry, "phone")
assert hasattr(registry, "car")

assert registry.car == ["car1", "car2"]
assert registry.phone == ["phone1", "phone2"]  # This fails
```

How do I define the code withing the property to be truly dynamic and get access to the individual list values in the dict?

Comment: You are overcomplicating things. All you need is a dotted-notation dict wrapper, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279212/how-to-use-dot-notation-for-dict-in-python) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352181/how-to-use-a-dot-to-access-members-of-dictionary) (and there are many more examples, just search for "python dict dot notation")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't setup properties in `__new__`, that gets called for every `Registry` object created! Instead, just assign the properties outside the class definition.

Secondly, this trips a lot of people up, but if you use a `lambda` inside a for-loop and you want to use the `item` variable, you need to make sure that you add an argument called `item` with the default value of `item`, otherwise all the properties will refer to the last `item` of the loop.

```
class Registry:
    def __init__(self):
        self._elements = defaultdict(list)

    def register(self, element_type, item):
        self._elements[element_type.value].append(item)

    def get(self, element_type):
        return self._elements[element_type.value]


for item in ElementTypes:
    prop_name = item.value
    prop = property(lambda self, item=item: self.get(item))

    setattr(Registry, prop_name.lower(), prop)
```