# jmespath: how to search a dict of dict structure

Tags: python, json, dictionary, jmespath

There's an example of search in the tutorial going:

```
{
  "machines": [
    {"name": "a", "state": "running"},
    {"name": "b", "state": "stopped"},
    {"name": "b", "state": "running"}
  ]
}
In [68]: jmespath.search("machines[?state=='running'].name",p)
Out[68]: ['a', 'b']
```

However, my structure uses a dictionary rather than a list, e.g.:

```
In [64]: q={
    ...:   "machines": {
    ...:     "m1":     {"name": "a", "state": "running"},
    ...:     "m2":     {"name": "b", "state": "stopped"},
    ...:     "m3":     {"name": "c", "state": "running"}
    ...:     }
    ...:     }
```

My different attempts to parse this have failed:

```
In [65]: jmespath.search("machines[?state=='running'].name",q)
# no output
In [66]: jmespath.search("machines.*[?state=='running'].name",q)
Out[66]: []

In [67]: jmespath.search("machines[*][?state=='running'].name",q)
# no output
```

How can I perform this search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`*` wildcard expression](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#wildcard-expressions) to select all values from a hash:

```
>>> jmespath.search("machines.*", q)
[{'name': 'a', 'state': 'running'}, {'name': 'b', 'state': 'stopped'}, {'name': 'c', 'state': 'running'}]
```

Now you have the same structure as before, so you can add `[?state=='running'].name` to it. Do put the above expression into parentheses, you want it to apply to the array output of the wildcard, not to each individual value in the `machines` mapping:

```
(machines.*)[?state=='running'].name
```

or use a [pipe expression](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#pipe-expressions):

```
machines.* | [?state=='running'].name
```

Both give you the desired output:

```
>>> jmespath.search("(machines.*)[?state=='running'].name", q)
['a', 'c']
>>> jmespath.search("machines.* | [?state=='running'].name", q)
['a', 'c']
```