# Is there a compact way to unpack some values from a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, iterable-unpacking

I encounter the current situation many times in my codes. I define a dictionary.

```py
params = {
    'color': 'green',
    'xlim': (0, 250),
    'ylim': (0, 10),
    'ylabel': 'the label',
    'xlabel': 'time'
}
```

Then, inside the definition of some functions, I unpack some values from a dictionary like the above into a tuple

```
color, ylim, ylabel, xlabel = params['color'], params['ylim'], params['ylabel'], params['xlabel']
```

I imagine there should be a better way to do this unpacking. So I tried the following

```py
color, ylim, ylabel, xlabel = params['color','ylim','ylabel','xlabel']
```

but it gives an error.

```
KeyError: ('color', 'ylim', 'ylabel', 'xlabel')
```

So, my questions are

- Is there a more compact way to unpack **some values** from a dictionary in Python?
- Is unpacking a dictionary like this a bad practice?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about `**`. I am reading about it to see if it can help.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
params = {
    'color': 'green',
    'xlim': (0, 250),
    'ylim': (0, 10),
    'ylabel': 'the label',
    'xlabel': 'time'
}
color, ylim, ylabel, xlabel = (params[x] for x in ('color', 'ylim', 'ylabel', 'xlabel'))
print(color)
```

Out:

```
green
```

Comment: Yes, list (tuple?) comprehensions! I forgot about them. What do you think about my second question?

Comment: @sfx This is actually a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

Comment: It's fine. In case you heavily use dictionary values, there is a lot of overhead typing. Sometimes I wish an (additional) 'dot notation' for dicts. Just `params.color`.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16279578/8142021) about the 'dot notation'. It might be better indeed.

Comment: @sfx: Yes for flat dicts this is fine, but not for nested ones.