# How to get nested dictionary key value with .get()

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, nested-properties

With a simple dictionary like:

```
myDict = {'key1':1, 'key2':2}
```

I can safely use:

```
print myDict.get('key3')
```

and even while 'key3' is not existent no errors will be thrown since .get() still returns None.

Now how would I achieve the same simplicity with a nested keys dictionary:

```
myDict={}
myDict['key1'] = {'attr1':1,'attr2':2}
```

The following will give a KeyError:

```
print myDict.get('key1')['attr3']
```

This will go through:

```
print myDict.get('key1').get('attr3')
```

but it will fail with adn AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get':

```
print myDict.get('key3').get('attr1')
```

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352181/how-to-use-a-dot-to-access-members-of-dictionary

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) accepts additional `default` parameter. The `value` is returned instead of `None` if there's no such key.

```
print myDict.get('key1', {}).get('attr3')
```

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352181/how-to-use-a-dot-to-access-members-of-dictionary

Comment: Note that `myDict.get('key1', {})` can *still* return `None` if `myDict['key1'] = None` is set explicitly. I would actually recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23463709/3694363) approach.

Comment: @PavelVergeev, My answer, and the other answer you linked both will raise `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` in such case. ;)

Comment: what can be passed on the empty curly braces ? what is this for ? thanks

Comment: @Gel, `{}` in python is a dictionary (hash map) literal. It's used as a fallback value in case of there's no `'key1'` entry in `myDict`.

Answer (score 8):

There is a very nice [blog post from Dan O'Huiginn](http://ohuiginn.net/mt/2010/07/nested_dictionaries_in_python.html) on the topic of nested dictionaries.  He ultimately suggest subclassing dict with a class that handles nesting better.  Here is the subclass modified to handle your case trying to access keys of non-dict values:

```
class ndict(dict):
     def __getitem__(self, key):
         if key in self: return self.get(key)
         return self.setdefault(key, ndict())
```

You can reference nested existing keys or ones that don't exist.  You can safely use the bracket notation for access rather than .get().  If a key doesn't exist on a NestedDict object, you will get back an empty NestedDict object.  The initialization is a little wordy, but if you need the functionality, it could work out for you.  Here are some examples:

```
In [97]: x = ndict({'key1': ndict({'attr1':1, 'attr2':2})})

In [98]: x
Out[98]: {'key1': {'attr1': 1, 'attr2': 2}}

In [99]: x['key1']
Out[99]: {'attr1': 1, 'attr2': 2}

In [100]: x['key1']['key2']
Out[100]: {}

In [101]: x['key2']['key2']
Out[101]: {}

In [102]: x['key1']['attr1']
Out[102]: 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Use exceptions:

```
try:
    print myDict['key1']['attr3']
except KeyError:
    print "Can't find my keys"
```

Comment: Now why the hell couldn't I have thought of that?!?

Answer (score 0):

That's normal since key3 doesn't exist so

```
myDict.get('key3')
```

returns none..

NoneType object has no attribute..

So you have to store the value of myDict.get('key3'), test if it's not null and then use the get method on the stored item

Answer (score 0):

`NestedDict` allows you to handle nested dictionaries with the same interface of a standard dictionary.

```
from ndicts.ndicts import NestedDict

my_dict = {'key1': {'attr1': 1,'attr2': 2}
nd = NestedDict(my_dict)
```

```
>>> nd.get(("key1", "attr3"), "not found")
'not found'
>>> nd.get(("key3", "attr1"), "not found")
'not found'
```

To install [ndicts](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts)

```
pip install ndicts
```

Answer (score 0):

I improve the solution proposed by jxstandford to handle list in dict.

```py
class NestedDict(dict):

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self:
            return self.to_nested(self.get(key))
        return self.setdefault(key, NestedDict())


    @staticmethod
    def to_nested(obj: Any) -> Any:
        if not obj:
            return NestedDict()
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            return NestedDict(obj)
        if isinstance(obj, list):
            return list(map(NestedDict.to_nested, obj))
        return obj
```

So it can handle dict like that :

```py
foo = {"bar": [{"a:":3}]}
{} == foo["bar"][0]["b"]
```