# Fetching nested value given dot notation

Tags: python

I have the following structure in my json:

```
obj = {
  'Name': 'David',
  'Car': {
           'Make': 'Ford',
           'Year': 2008
   }
}
```

I am given dot notation to refer to the object value, for example:

```
Car.Make ==> 'Form'
```

Given a string, such  as `"Car.Make"`, how would I programmatically fetch the attribute? In the above example, it would be:

```
obj.get('Car').get('Make')
```

But what about for a deeply-nested object, how would I extract the value given dot notation of `"Attr1.Attr2.Attr3...Attrn"` ?

Comment: I don't think there's going to be a solution that's syntactically valid for both Java and Python.

Comment: @Kevin sorry Java was a mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
obj = {
  'Name': 'David',
  'Car': {
           'Make': 'Ford',
           'Year': 2008
   }
}
s = "Car.Make"
x = obj
keys = s.split(".")
for key in keys:
    x = x[key]
print(x)
```

Result:

```
Ford
```

---

Or, in one-liner form:

```
from functools import reduce
print(reduce(lambda a,b: a[b], s.split("."), obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some answers from Stackoverflow that propose a custom dictionary class that implements `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` to access the dictionary items:

- [How to use a dot "." to access members of dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352181/how-to-use-a-dot-to-access-members-of-dictionary)
- [Accessing dict keys like an attribute in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984647/accessing-dict-keys-like-an-attribute-in-python)

Comment: I missed the fact that you are given a string, sorry!