# How to grab dict value from string of square bracket notation

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary

Let's say I have the dictionary `my_dict`:

```
my_dict = {"vms": {"vm": {"name": "test-vm", "desc": "test"}}}
```

Obviously, in code I can grab the VM data with:

```
my_dict['vms']['vm']
```

More to the point, I can create an object of vms with that value and then reference the data:

```
vms = my_dict['vms']
vm = vms['vm']
```

My question is, if I were to save the value `vms['vm']` as a string in a configuration file, how can I then use said string to grab the value from the dictionary?  Something like:

```
my_dict.grab("vms['vm']")    # To grab my_dict['vms']['vm']
```

I'm hoping a solution that I can further use with, say, `vms['vm']['name']` regardless of how nested it gets, akin to Ansible Facts in a YAML playbook:

```
my_dict.grab("vms['vm']['name']")
```

Comment: That would be unnecessarily difficult. Why not store something like "vms.vm" or "vms.vm.name" instead?

Comment: It's fairly easy if you agree to use dot notation strings instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32404277/1453822

Comment: Important to understand, when you say "  I can create an object of vms with that value " that *isnt' what you are doing*. You aren't creating an object at all when you do: `vms = my_dict['vms']`... you are *assigning an existing object to the name `vms`*

Comment: In any case, storing that string as a value in a configuration file doesn't make sense. **Strings are not source code** I mean, you can use `exec`/`eval` to dynamically evaluate a string as source code, but that is extremely hackey. Just pick a format which is easy to parse and work with programmatically

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I understand the oddity of the request generally, but I'm trying to build a system with a similar workflow to an Ansible Playbook a la {{ ansible_facts["eth0"]["ipv4"]["address"] }}

Comment: Yeah, so they are probably just using `eval`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I just got it working, I'm going to guess they use Jinja2 directly

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out what I was looking for was Jinja2

```
from jinja2 import Template

my_dict = {"vms": {"vm": {"name": "test-vm", "desc": "test"}}}
string_location = "{{ vms['vm'] }}"

print(Template(string_location).render(my_dict))
```