# Print an object's attributes like json.dumps prints a dict

Tags: python, class, object, dictionary

**EDIT**: a solution is in this answer: [How to use a dot “.” to access members of dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23689767/1422096)

When using a dict:

```
d = dict()
d['param1'] = 17
d['param2'] = 3
```

it's easy to print it with  `print json.dumps(d)`. When using an object / class:

```
class z: 
    pass
z.param1 = 17
z.param2 = 3
```

**I can't manage to print all the attributes of z, neither with `print json.dumps(z)`, nor with `print z`. How to do it?**

---

*Sidenote but important: why do I want to use a class / object to store parameters, when it would be logical to use a dict? Because `z.param1` is much shorter and handy to write than `z['param1']`, especially with my (french) keyword `[`, `]`, `'`are quit long to write because ALT+GR+5 (let's say 2 seconds instead of 0.5, but this really matters when you have a long code with many variables)*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-function-in-python-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of

Comment: @Anil Or something else : would there be a short hack (by subclassing `dict`) for accessing a dict with `d.param1` instead of `d['param1']` ?

Comment: is this what you are looking for ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/23689767/2652580

Answer (score 3):

You may simply use `__dict__` on a class instance to get the attributes in the form of `dict` object as:

```
>>> z.__dict__
>>> {'param1': 17, '__module__': '__main__', 'param2': 3, '__doc__': None}
```

However, if you need to remove the `__xxx__` inbuilt methods then you may need to specify the `__str__` method inside the class.

Comment: Can you give an example about what you said about `__str__`?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: This output, @ZdaR : `{'param1': 17, 'param2': 3}`