# how to pass self to function inside python dictionary

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dictionary

I'm trying to store a function in python dictionary that minipulates some ranges from the dictionary it self, but I don't how to pass `self` to the function, ex:

```
d = {"r": range(10), "r2": range(10, 20), "f": lambda self: self["r"].extend(self["r2"])}
```

I expect it to return extended list like: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]`

but when I call `d["f"]()` I get `TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given).`

even when I do `d["f"](d)` I get nothing !

```
>>> d["f"](d)
>>>
```

so is it even possible ? and how ?
thank in advanced.

**UPDATE 1**

I want to pass **self** to the dictionary to filter the some values within the dictionary, and classing is not an option because my case is to use that in google-app-engine [here's my question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983340/how-to-subclass-google-app-engine-ndb-property-to-support-python-subclassed-obje)

so classing won't work (I've got to this because I can't store classes in datastore so I use subclassed dictionaries instead see my other question above)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second usage, `d["f"](d)`, is correct.

However, `list.extend` does not return anything - so you don't see anything in the terminal. It is, however, extending the list:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x.extend([4, 5]) # nothing is returned here
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Also, you should avoid calling the parameter to the function `self` - it has other purposes when using classes.

---

It seems that your need is a perfect use case for a class of this form:

```
class MyData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.r = range(10)
        self.r2 = range(10, 20)

    def f(self):
        self.r.extend(self.r2)
        return self.r
```

To use it:

```
d = MyData()
d.f() # prints out your expected result
```

Comment: that's correct thank you, but shall I pass the whole dictionary to the function to get it to work ?!!

Comment: @user5258689 You might want to look into using classes - you'll be able to accomplish what you want in a much simpler (and Pythonic) way.

Answer (score 2):

Use a closure - the function that remembers its environment. You don't need to pass anything into `d["f"]`, all the information can be already present:

```
def make_d():
    d = {"r": range(10), "r2": range(10, 20), "f": lambda: d["r"].extend(d["r2"])}
    return d

the_d = make_d()
the_d["f"]()
the_d
# => {'r': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], 'r2': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], 'f': <function <lambda> at 0x105c76c80>}
```

Rushy is correct though: this is a literal solution to your problem, and using classes properly would likely make this a non-issue (but of course YMMV).

Comment: that's quite useful thank you, the problem is that I want this to work in google-app-engine with some issues from this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983340/how-to-subclass-google-app-engine-ndb-property-to-support-python-subclassed-obje