# Python short-circuiting method coalesce chain

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonetype

I often see this pattern to navigate through dictionaries in a fault-tolerant manner:

```
a.get('k1', {}).get('k2', {}).get('k3', '')
```

This is, however, not possible if the intermediary objects are class instances rather than dictionaries. Is there a terse way to do (something like) the following:

```
a?.method1()?.method2()?.method3()...
```

Expanding to:

```
if a is None:
    return None
obj = a.method1()
if obj is None:
    return None
obj = obj.method2()
if obj is None:
    return None
obj = obj.method3()
return obj
```

I guess it might be possible with some variant of the builder pattern, but that would not be feasible if the methods above are in an API not controlled by the user.

Comment: You might be interested in my answer to another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879946/the-most-pythonic-way-to-access-elements-of-a-dict/47880053#47880053). Although it uses a custom dictionary implementation.

Comment: @Skam Maybe, but in this case the query cannot be a simple iterable of key strings; it would have to be an iterable of lambdas.

Comment: you need a "Maybe" monad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest equivalent would be to use `getattr` with a default value:

```
>>> class A: pass
...
>>> a = A()
>>> getattr(getattr(getattr(a, 'k1', A()), 'k2', A()), 'k3', A())
<__main__.A object at 0x104a7de10>
```

However, this above construction has major code-smell for me... why can you not rely on an object having an attribute?

Although, if you are chaining *method calls* then you would probably want a default callable that returns some convenient default value, e.g.:

```
>>> def empty(): return A()
...
>>> getattr(getattr(getattr(a, 'k1', empty)(), 'k2', empty)(), 'k3', empty)()
<__main__.A object at 0x104a7dda0>
>>>
```

If tersness is a concern, then maybe use `reduce`:

```
>>> def getter(obj, k):
...     return getattr(obj, k,  A())
...
>>> functools.reduce(getter, ('k1','k2','k3'), a)
<__main__.A object at 0x104a7dda0>
```

Honestly, I would use intermediate variables and explicitly call the methods and use exception handling, that would be the more Pythonic way.

Comment: It's not that I can't rely on an object having an attribute; it's that the return value of an object's method is often None.

Comment: @Reinderien like a `Node` class with `left_child`, for example?

Comment: Yes, in fact a very similar application from BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 1):

Burn me alive for using eval but I occasionally like to use try...eval in cases where there are nested attributes.

```
try:
    val = eval("obj.{a1}.{a2}.{a3}".format(a1=a1, a2=a2, a3=a3))
except AttributeError:
    val = default
    print('Attribute not found')
except Exception as e:
    print('Something went wrong')
```

This looks nicer than multiple getattr's imo and I like to catch for AttributeErrors. Plus, it's pretty robust since you can do a lot of string manipulations to get just what you want. I also feel that this aligns with the "ask for forgiveness" schtick.

Comment: Some methods require more forgiveness than others... :P

Comment: what's the purpose of `eval` in this context?