# using variable value in other variable

Tags: python

I have a variable such as:

```
x = 'HELLO'
```

I want to access a DIC using the following string

```
self.dname.x[0]
```

which inherenlty should mean

```
self.dname.HELLO[0]
```

what is the proper way to do this in python?  What is the proper term for this type of variable?

Comment: We need more information. What is the type of dname?

Comment: I believe the OP's usage of "DIC" is short for [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) @KevinMGranger.

Comment: I don't agree. I think it means [Dependency Injection Container](http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html) (php link but still applicable).

Comment: @blonc we need a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `self.dname` is a dictionary:

```
self.dname[x][0]
```

`x` is an "index" variable - you are using it to find the data you want.  Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2352181/2877364) going the other way.

**Example:** (tested in Python 2 and 3)

```
>>> foo={'HELLO': [1,2,3]}
>>> foo
{'HELLO': [1, 2, 3]}
>>> foo.HELLO[0]                          <--- doesn't work
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'HELLO'
>>> x='HELLO'
>>> foo[x][0]                             <--- works fine
1
```

You asked about `self.x`.  If `x` is a regular variable, you don't reference it with `self.` (as in the example above).  If `x` is a member of your class, then yes, you will need to use `self.x`.  However, if you are carrying around a key and a dictionary, you might consider redesigning your data structures to carry the resulting value instead.

Comment: thanks cxw - q: it seems that if self.x = 'HELLO' that means i also always need to add self.x with in the [self.x] is that proper?  seems like a lot of extra work to add self every place.

Comment: @blonc Updated - let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: If x is a member of your class (self refers to the instance of that class), then yes, you will need to do that. Your given example doesn't show that, however.

Comment: Was directed at blonc. Forgot to throw a tag in there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand the question, but you might want to have a look at the `getattr` builtin function (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).

For example, in your case (again, if I understand correctly) :

```
x = 'HELLO'
getattr(self.dname, x)[0]
```