# how to pass multiple arguments in python using dot operator

Tags: python

I like to know is there way to access elements in an object using .(dot) operator (`show_letters.a`) without creating a class. I know I can access in following way

```
def show_letters(letters):
    print(letters['a'])


def main():
    letters = {"a": 2, "b": 3, "c":4}
    show_letters(letters)

main()
```

how can access `show_letters.a` or is it possible?

Comment: What? Neither `show_letters` (the function) not `letters` (the dictionary) have an `a` attribute. And how is that related to the arguments? What output are you expecting?

Comment: Here is the answer (you should extends default dict class):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352181/how-to-use-a-dot-to-access-members-of-dictionary

Comment: the dot notation is for attributes of a class object. The square brackets are for indexing and slicing, a la `letters['a']`. The parentheses are for calling a function (or method of a class). Those are not interchangeable. (With the exception of a few cases, like pandas columns, which should really be called with `[]` anyway, but that's just my (correct) opinion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do is access a value in a dictionary with the dot operator, you're not going to be able to do it without creating a class. It would be class that inherits from dict and overrides the `__getattr__` method. Dictionaries do have the `get` method though, I would use that one.

You could save your data as attributes of any object too, but that's not really a good idea.