# Cleaner way to get this value from nested dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, object, nested

I am using Python to retrieve a list of record data. This data has secondary record data inside of it. I come from Java background so to me it is a nested object.

Anyway to get a value from the nested object I currently do the following.

```
Acc = bankAccounts[0]
BAN = Acc['Bank_Details__r']
Records = BAN['records']
Fields = Records[0]
Id = Fields['Id']
print(Id)
```

While this works fine and all, I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: What’s up with those variable names? Can you share more of your program? It might be possible to change other areas in order to avoid this deeply nested access entirely.

Comment: `Id = bankAccounts[0]['Bank_Details__r']['records'][0]['Id']`? That's assuming the nested structure is *guaranteed*.  If not, you will need to do additional handling on the appropriate levels.

Comment: There is not much to the rest of the program except a query to get the bankAccounts list from my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not *really*. You *could* make it all a single line (which I assume you know), or you can [pretty easily subclass dict to enable dot notation access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23689767/1453822) which you may consider cleaner.

Other than that, what you have is the best you can get.