# How do I create a callable object to mimic an API call?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I create a object that I can invoke to mimic the following api call and response. I am aware of the mock library but the use case prohibits me from using it.

```
response = client.users.create(email='test@gmail.com', phone=123)
outcome = response.ok
```

My current solution below works however I feel like there is a more pythonic and generic way to do this so I can mimic other calls without having to rewrite different inner classes

```
class Client:
    ok = True
    class users:
        class create():
            ok = True
            def __init__(self, email, phone):
                pass
```

Input

```
client = Client()
response = client.users.create(email='test@gmail.com', phone=123)
response.ok
```

Output

```
True
```

Comment: You could use a dictionary. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2352181/5987698).

Comment: Interesting, however using dot notation on a dictionary does not work in this case because I need to be able to pass arguments using 'create' ...

Comment: `create` could be a function stored in the dictionary, with the key "users" then?