# Python - standard library's support for turning dict into attributes-dict

Tags: python, dictionary, object, attributes

I wonder if there's standard library's support in Python for doing next thing:

```
x = {'foo': 123, 'bar': 'hello'}
y = std_lib.attr_dict(x)
y.onemore = [1,2,3]
print(y.foo, y['foo'], y.bar, y['bar'], y.onemore, y['onemore'], y.get('notexist', 'NE'))
# prints: 123 123 hello hello [1,2,3] [1,2,3] NE
print(list(dict(y).keys())) # Back conversion to dict
# prints: ['foo', 'bar', 'onemore']
```

Like there is `collections` standard library, it might have such `attr_dict()` class.

I'm pretty sure there are good implementations of this in `pip` modules, can you suggest the most-popular/most-rich `pip` modules for doing that?

Or maybe it can be also achieved in just few lines of pure Python code somehow?

Also would be interesting to support nested dictionaries/attributes, like `y.first.second = 123`.

Comment: `types.SimpleNamespace(**x)` may be what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32107024/10786110 - replace `iteritems` with `items` (Python 3)