# Recursively set object attributes from dict

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

My question is relatively simple: How do I recursively set object attributes matching the key-value pairs of a dictionary?

For example, given this dict:

```py
my_dict = {
    "number": 0,
    "thing": True,
    "foo": {
        "bar": {
            "thing": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make an object with its keys as attributes, recursively:

```py
>>> my_obj = some_method(my_dict)
>>> my_obj.number
0
>>> my_obj.foo.bar
{"thing": "string"}
>>> my_obj.foo.bar.thing
"string"
```

Comment: So recursively swap keys/values?

Comment: Dictionary elements are accessed using indexing, not as attributes.

Comment: `my_obj["foo"]["bar"]["thing"]`

Comment: See [What is the best way to implement nested dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries)

Comment: @Jab yes, https://stackoverflow.com/a/32107024/13837757 works quite nicely, I was just thinking the answer could be simplified to a function.

Comment: Also see [Accessing dict keys like an attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984647/accessing-dict-keys-like-an-attribute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way using builtin libs:

```
import json
from types import SimpleNamespace

my_dict = {
    "number": 0,
    "thing": True,
    "foo": {
        "bar": {
            "thing": "string"
        }
    }
}

dumped_data = json.dumps(my_dict)
result = json.loads(dumped_data, object_hook=lambda x: SimpleNamespace(**x))

result.number

>> 0

result.foo.bar.thing

>> string
```

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/Infinidat/munch

This library is meant to provide attribute style access to dictionaries.

For example:

```
>>> from munch import munchify
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}, 'd': ["hi", {'foo': "bar"}]}
>>> x = munchify(d)
>>> x.a
1
>>> x.b.c
2
>>> x.d[1].foo
'bar'
```

Comment: Of course there's a library for this kind of thing, just couldn't find it with a Google search, thanks!

Comment: Are you being sarcastic?

Comment: Do you want me to say I was being sarcastic? No, right? Then no, I wasn't being sarcastic.