# Convert search string to searchable keys from dictionary in python

Tags: python

Folks,
I am using solution described at following location
[How to use a dot "." to access members of dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352181/how-to-use-a-dot-to-access-members-of-dictionary)

I will minimize the solution here to explain the objective.
Basically I am looking for a solution that can take nested keys structure in string format from the user and queries dictionary. I used solution above to convert dictionary in dot notation searchable format. However following is where I am stuck

```
data = {
"Country" : {
    "US" : [ {"Connecticut" : "Hartford"} , {"California" : "Sacramento"} ]
}

### Following works
f = Map(data)
print(f.Country.US[1].California)

Sacramento

### Following does not work
s = 'Country.US[1].California'
print(f[s])
```

What I need is a solution that could take externally provided key structure and turns into searchable dot-notation

What can be done?

Comment: So you want to input `'Country.US[1].California'` and output `'Sacramento'`?

Comment: yes,  The input will be string

Comment: the janky and basic way would be to use exec to treat the string as a variable
`exec(f"print(f.{s})")`

Comment: You can use `eval` but need to process the input string a bit to convert to a format like: `"['Country']['US'][1]['California']"`. Something like: `eval("data" + '[' + "][".join([f"{x[:-1]}" if ']' == x[-1] else f"'{x}'" for x in re.split(r"[\.\[]", s)]) + "]")`

Comment: @benjababe solution seems to work but its print statement, what I need to do is return the result from queried dictionary back to other app. so somehow exec(f"print(f.{s})") needs to be saved in variable and so I can return. Any suggestion there.