# python override dot syntax functionality in a class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, python-class

is this possible? I want to assign a value to a custom dictionary using <class_name>.<attribute_name> syntax.

here's an example:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__values__ = {}
    def add_a_value_using_dot_syntax(self, index, value): # what should this be?
        self.__values__[index] = value

bar = Foo()
bar.baz = 'hello'

print(bar.baz) # hello
print(bar.__values__) # {'baz': 'hello'}
```

I know that this can be done with bracket syntax by overriding `__setitem__` but it doesn't seem to work for dot syntax..

Thanks

Comment: can you please elaborate on exactly what you want to do?

Comment: You can put whatever code you want in a getter and setter; can you clarify what information you need that is not already answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2627034/6273251)?

Comment: Please show an [mcve] to illustrate what you are trying to do. This can even be pseudocode or not entirely correct python as long as you make it clear which parts you are guessing at and want to do.

Comment: In a class method, you can do `self.foobar = "baz"`. This is the same as you already do in `__init__()`.

Comment: yes but i want to assign arbitrary attributes to the class and somehow have them stored in a dictionary other than `__dict__` (`__values__` in the example). I did this with `__setitem__` already but it doesn't work for dot syntax, only bracket syntax.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352181/how-to-use-a-dot-to-access-members-of-dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to override `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`, but since these are fundamental to how the class works, you'd need some extra logic, and there's an enormous minefield of potentially undefined behavior. I think you'd want

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__values__ = {}
        super().__init__()

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == '__values__':
            self.__dict__['__values__'] = value
            return
        try:
            self.__getattr__(name)
        except AttributeError:
            self.__values__[name] = value
        return super().__setattr__(name, value)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == '__values__':
            return self.__dict__['values']
        try:
            return super().__getattr__(name)
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                return self.__values__[name]
            except KeyError:
                raise AttributeError
```

This is extremely evil/cursed, and should never be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can override [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)/[`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)/[`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__)/[`__delattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delattr__) to do what you want.

However, you should be *very* careful when doing so.  A lot of code will make assumptions about the attributes of your objects, and it is very easy to break standard data model contracts in a way that makes your class unusable in certain contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Use `__setattr__` instead of `__setitem__`. This method is *always* called, so you'll want some logic that decides what to do based on the value of the attribute being assigned to.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._values = {}  # Do not invent new dunder names

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in ["baz", "v1", "v2"]:  # e.g.
            self._values['name'] = value
        else:
            # Assign to name "normally"
            super().__setattr__(name, value)
```