# getattr throws TypeError on ImageSpecField

Tags: python, django, django-imagekit

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    original_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_to)

    thumbnail = ImageSpecField(
        processors=thumbnail_processors,
        source='original_image',
        format='PNG'
    )
    ...

obj = MyModel()
val = getattr(obj, 'thumbnail')
```

... this gives me the following error: "TypeError: can't pickle instancemethod objects"

Django 1.7.1
ImageKit 3.2.4

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049849/why-cant-i-pickle-this-object

Comment: Why dont you do: val = obj.thumbnail ?

Comment: @doniyor, this code is just to demonstrate the problem. I need to be able to dynamically access attributes of the instance. My code goes through a list of attributes per instance in a list of instances.